# Need *.aux file in separate folder

Tags: auxiliary-files

When compiling with `pdflatex` we need the `*.aux` files in a separate folder.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: MiKTeX's pdf(ta)tex has a `-aux-directory=DIR`

Comment: `pdflatex --output-dir=temp mytexsource.tex` is the one-line answer buried down. Here, `temp` subdirectory is used to store all intermediate files while compiling the file named `mytexsource.tex`

Comment: Mostly the same question: [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files)

Comment: See also another answer that uses `cd`: [pdftex - Output-directory can't write on file log, linux terminal - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328560/output-directory-cant-write-on-file-log-linux-terminal)

Answer (score 89):

With MiKTeX and TeX Live you can use `--output-directory=dir`. This will put all output files including `.log` and `.pdf`/`.dvi` in this directory (and append it to the search path so that auxiliary files are found).

In MiKTeX you can additionally set `--aux-directory=dir` which will put only the auxiliary files in this directory.

**Edit 2023**: I do not recommend to use this options. In my opinion it only make compilation complicated and personnally I never used that.

Comment: I'm using MikTex/TeXworks on 64Bit-Windows7 and am experiencing issue described in OP. Where do I put this 'output-directory=dir' in the config.txt file?

Comment: Jeez, why doesn't `pdflatex` have this option.

Comment: @Daniel It does. You need to specify the option before the filename though.

Comment: I am afraid the option `--output-directory=dir` is not better than compiling the latex file from the directory `dir`. (e.g., running `cd dir` and `pdflatex <or latexmk> ../filename.tex`). I agree that the option is convenient. Is there a way to redirect the generated pdf file alone?

Answer (score 23):

If you compile your document using [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara), we can write a rule to move selected files to an arbitrary directory. This is my humble attempt with the `move.yaml` plain rule:

<sub>This answer was rewritten to comply with the new 3.0 version of `arara`. For `arara` 2.0, see the revision.</sub>

```yaml
!config
# Move rule for arara
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: move
name: Move
command: <arara> @{isFalse(file == getOriginalFile(), isWindows("cmd /c move /y", "mv -f").concat(' "').concat(file).concat('"').concat(' "').concat(target).concat('"'))}
arguments:
- identifier: target
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.target}
```

<sup>The rule should work on all platforms, provided that the target directory exists. I could write a more complicated rule, but I don't think we need to make things difficult here. `:)`</sup>

Now, we need to add the `move` directive to our `mydoc.tex` document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: move: { files: [ mydoc.log, mydoc.aux ], target: stuff }
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

After compiling the document via `pdflatex`, `arara` will move the `.aux` and `.log` files to the `stuff` directory:

```
mydoc.tex
mydoc.pdf
stuff/
 |- mydoc.aux
 |- mydoc.log
```

We can also use other targets, say:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: move: { files: [ mydoc.log, mydoc.aux ], target: '/home/paulo/Documents/stuff' }
% arara: move: { files: [ mydoc.pdf ], target: '/home/paulo/Documents/articles' }
\documentclass{article}
....
```

`arara` 3.0 has also a `items` iterator, so we could write a different `move.yaml` rule:

```yaml
!config
# Move rule for arara
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: move
name: Move
command: <arara> @{isFalse(isEmpty(item), isWindows("cmd /c move /y", "mv -f").concat(' "').concat(getBasename(file)).concat('.').concat(item).concat('"').concat(' "').concat(target).concat('"'))}
arguments:
- identifier: target
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.target}
```

For this new rule, we simply provide the extension we want to move to the target:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: move: { items: [ log, aux ], target: stuff }
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

After compiling the document via `pdflatex`, `arara` will move `mydoc.aux` and `mydoc.log` files to the `stuff` directory (the rule says that's the main file basename + the provided extension):

```
mydoc.tex
mydoc.pdf
stuff/
 |- mydoc.aux
 |- mydoc.log
```

Other rules can be written, but for now I think it's enough. `:)`

Comment: Why not `move.yaml` is a part of arara by defauls? Also, can it create the folder `stuff` if it doesn't exist already?

Comment: @Harish: personally, I'm not fond of moving files, I prefer deleting them (hence the `clean` rule instead). `:)` Since `arara 3.0` is now released in the wild, I'm thinking of creating a `contrib/` folder in the project repository to keep other rules that aren't in the default set. `:)` About the directory creation, I need to take a look at the flags of each command; if `stuff` doesn't exist *as a directory*, the file will be *renamed* as `stuff`.

Comment: @PauloCereda ... moving files has the advantage that log files are kept when we need to search for errors. I would also vote for a move and for a feature to assure that the directory is created if not already there.

Comment: Could we have an update for move.yaml for arara-v4?

Answer (score 17):

You could also use [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) to do the job for you.
`auxdir` is the directory for all auxiliary files **but not the PDF** file.

`latexmk -auxdir=/tmp test.tex` should work. You can extend this to autocompile with `latexmk -auxdir=/tmp -pdf -pvc test.tex`

The manual `man latexmk` explains more about the `auxdir` parameter:

```
   -auxdir=FOO or -aux-directory=FOO
          Sets the directory for  auxiliary  output  files  of  (pdf)latex
          (.aux,  .log  etc).  This achieves its effect by the -aux-direc‐
          tory option of (pdf)latex, which currently is  only  implemented
          on the MiKTeX version of (pdf)latex.

          See   also   the   -outdir/-output-directory  options,  and  the
          $aux_dir,  $out_dir,  and  $search_path_separator  configuration
          variables  of  latexmk.  In particular, see the documentation of
          $out_dir for some complications  on  what  directory  names  are
          suitable.

          If you also use the -cd option, and the specified auxiliary out‐
          put directory is a relative path, then the path  is  interpreted
          relative to the document directory.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not hear about latexmk before, it is fantastic and make life a little easier!

Comment: Nice idea, though as the documentation says, it only works with MikTex. If you have TexLive, not only are the files not put there, but latexmk expects to see them there and when it doesn't find them it returns an error.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using the filesystem.  Here's a suggested workflow, which I'll illustrate with Bash/Unix, but which can be made to work on Windows: in your working directory, where you edit your Tex file and want your output to be produced, you have `build`, which is either a subdirectory, or a symlink to some build directory elsewhere.

1. Set up the directory:

   1. Either `mkdir build` in the directory where you want to work, or create the symlink to Bash.  If you use a subdirectory, then most flavours of Tex will be able to access resources in the working directory, as it is a parent directory.
   2. If $FILE is the basename of the Tex file you want to compile, then `ln -s "$FILE".tex build`
   3. If you are creating PDF output, then `ln -s build/$FILE.pdf .`
2. To run the Tex command, you can just run it in the build directory.  Or you can create a wrapper for the executable (untested): with the following shell function you can have aliases such as `alias pdflatex="runtexinbuild pdflatex"` which will run in the builddirectory if it is there, otherwise give the usual behaviour.

   ```
   runtexinbuild () { 
       local cmd="$1" status; shift
       if test -e build
       then pushd build
            command $cmd "$@"; status=$?
            popd
            exit $status
       else command $cmd "$@"
       fi; }
   ```

Comment: Where should I put the above code in Texstudio?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe I don't know Texstudio, but I think you can't run complex bash scripts in it.  You would either need to translate something like the above code into TS's scripting language, or call bash scripts from TS.  I recommend that you ask this as a question.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe Texstudio allows to give the explicit command for compilation. I am not sure whether we can given multiple commands there.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a TeXnicCenter-specific solution which will hopefully seem sound enough to the people claiming it's bad practice to have one single, huge repository for all LaTeX auxiliary files (which it probably is).

[image]

On the Build->Define Output Profiles menu, choose your standard build profile (say, LaTeX => PDF) and copy it to a project-specific profile. (Here, Dissertation.) Then add --aux-directory=directoryname to the command line arguments passed to MikTeX.

When compiling path/file.tex, this will create files as path/directoryname/file.aux, and so on. This should be enough of a compromise, I think.

EDIT: to work with BibTeX, this requires `%tm` to be changed to `./auxiliary/%tm` in the command line arguments passed to BibTeX. This can cause some trouble if external "chapter" files are `\include`d but this can be fixed by using `\input`. I suspect there's some deep reason for this but I don't know if there is another way around it.

Answer (score 2):

With TexMaker, you have a checkbox that allows you to put all the generated files in a separate folder named 'build'[image]

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX build wrapper [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) may be a solution. It avoids most of the pitfalls of using a separate folder for the auxiliary files by actually performing the compilation in a separate folder and then copying back the results. The separate folder can be specified with

```
ltx2any -t path_where_you_want_the_auxiliary_files_to_go filename.tex
```

For more options, see `ltx2any --help`.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a python module for saving the auxiliary files that are generated by LaTeX and BibTeX engines into a desired folder. On my GitHub site are more informations: https://github.com/amrane99/LaTeXCompiler. Once the module has been installed (using pip) you can simply compile the `.tex` file using pdflatex and no BibTeX engine as follows *-- the generated files will be stored in the `.aux_files folder` --*:

```
LaTeXCompiler -file <full_path_to_file>.tex 
              -tex_engine pdflatex -no_bib_engine -aux_folder .aux_files
```

It is important to not set `-aux_folder .aux_files` as `-aux_folder .aux` since this will interfere with the algorithm that copies the generated files into the folder, because the generated .aux file will have the same character sequence in it as the desired folder name, namely `.aux` and this is excluded, since the algorithm would try to move the folder into itself and might likely result in an error. A detailed description can be found [here](https://github.com/amrane99/LaTeXCompiler).

I hope this helps with the common issue of saving the auxiliary files in a separate folder so the working directory is always kept clean. This is very helpful for Mac users, since the `-aux-directory=DIR` does not work with the TexShop Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the auxiliary files only after the "complete" PDF output is generated. The "complete" means that the cross-reference is properly typeset.

Moving the auxiliary files will be easier if you create a make file (in Linux) or a batch file (in Windows).

An example of batch file (for Windows user) that not only compiles the input file several times (3 times should be enough) but also moves the auxiliary files to a specified folder at the end.

```
rem batch.bat

echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

rem %2 The number of times to invoke pdflatex in draftmode

rem %3 Folder name to which the auxiliary files will be moved

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" for /l %%x in (1,1,%2) do pdflatex --shell-escape -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~1.tex"

if exist "%~1.tex" pdflatex --shell-escape "%~1.tex"

if not exist "%~3" mkdir "%~3"

for %%x in (aux log out toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" move "%~1.%%x" "%~3")
```

`%1` represents the TeX input filename without extension, `%2` represents the number of times to invoke `pdflatex` in `draftmode`, and `%3` represents the folder name to which the auxiliary files will be moved.

Note that `pdflatex` will be executed `%2` plus one times in total.

### Exercise:

Assume we have an input file named `filename` and we want to invoke `pdflatex` twice in `draftmode` and the auxiliary files will be moved to `dir\subdir\`.

[image]

Comment: 3 times often isn't enough, much safer to check that the aux file is stable, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30674/document-requiring-infinitely-many-compiler-passes/79699#79699 for an extreme example

Answer (score -1):

You can use also [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org) together with [TeXlipse plugin](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net). It is quite easy to separate there your .tex files from all that are generated by TeX.