# Setting auxiliary files path in Aquamacs

Tags: pdftex, aquamacs, auctex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files)

I use Aquamacs and TeX Live 2009 to edit my Latex files. Is there a way to define a default or project-based path where the auxiliary output of latex is put? All my latex folders are cluttered with bbl or blg files.

Is there a possible setting, that latex puts the pdf in `folder A`, auxiliary files in `folder B` and assure that the preview still knows where to find the pdf?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/need-aux-file-in-seprate-folder

Comment: Both links are potential masters to dupe this one to - I'm not quite sure which to go for!

Comment: The question also includes where to put the pdflatex parameters in the Aquamacs setting. I came across the `--output-directory=dir` parameter several time, but I did not know where to specify this in Aquamacs...

Comment: This is probably far too late to help you @eric, but you can customize `TeX-command-extra-options` to be (for example) `"--output-directory=dir"`.  Of course, if you want dir to change for each file, then you'll have to add some elisp code to a hook etc.