# Running pdflatex the minimally necessary number of times for elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle, logging

Running `pdflatex` ONCE on

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}%%% version 3.1 from CTAN
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\author[1]{Johann Sebastian Bach}
\author[2]{Ludwig van Beethoven\corref{cor2}}
\cortext[cor2]{Corresponding author}%
\address[1]{Thomaskirche, Leipzig}
\address[2]{Zentralfriedhof Wien}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image: output of the first run]

As you see, the labels of both authors are 1, and the superscript star after Mr. Beethoven is missing. You need the second run of `pdflatex` to correct this issue.

However, running `pdflatex` ALWAYS at least twice is not what you want: it eats up your time, especially on large papers, whereas running `pdflatex` once might sometimes suffice if the right .aux files are available from a prior run. I looked into the .log file and the console output in an attempt to discover some hints on whether a second rerun is needed, but I could not find anything usable.  My prior approach to checking whether a rerun is needed is saying something like

```
MESSAGE_FOR_RERUN := '(LaTeX Warning: Label\(s\) may have changed\. Rerun to get cross\-references right\.)|(LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references\.)|(LaTeX Warning: Citation [^[:cntrl:]]* on page [0-9]* undefined on)|(Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations\.)|(\(mparhack\) *Rerun to get them right\.)'
```

in the beginning of a makefile and

```
for i in $(SOURCES); do \
  $(PDFLATEX) $$i ; \
done
if (egrep $(MESSAGE_FOR_RERUN) $(OBJECTS)); then \
  for i in $(SOURCES); do $(PDFLATEX) $$i ; done; \
fi
```

(where the variables are defined appropriately) in a rule of the makefile. (Of course, in a non-MWE, you might also need to run some choice of sed, awk, rm, bibtex, bibtex8, biber, makeglossaries, makeindex, xindy, dvi2ps, zip, chmod or god-knows-what in addition, but such details on other programs are all off-topic here.)

Of course, you can have `latexmk` or `\usepackage[mainaux]{rerunfilecheck}` do the job, but I wonder: can you continue doing it the previous way via makefiles, and if so, which string to search for in the log files?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, since after you compile the 2nd time, that problem disappears. If you need to compile it again it is because you changed or added some material, not because the title part. So, simply type, compile and be happy. Just make sure to run it 2 or 3 times before submit the paper.

Comment: So, take a look at `arara`. It has a lot of tools to automate.

Comment: `.log` file parsing alone can not be guaranteed to be enough to detect necessary reruns. The code you show here is a prime example of that. The only difference in the `.log` file between the two runs (on a clean directory) is the absence of the `.aux` (and `.spl`, no idea what that does) in the first run. You could detect the relevant message (`No file <\jobname>.aux.`) and rerun if it is found, that might give you false positives if the `.aux` file is not used for anything, but you can probably live with that. Now suppose you have run your document once or twice and the `.aux` is present ...

Comment: ... but then you need to add a third author with their own affiliation/`\address`. So you add `\author[3]{...}` and `\address[3]{...}`. You compile once to get a "1" for the their footnote instead of "*c*". The .log is identical (except for time and date and memory usage info) to the previous run. But still you need another run for the marker come out as "*c*". In this situation no amount of `.log` parsing can help you. It would have helped to compare the `.aux` files since they differ. IIRC `latexmk` actually compares all `.aux`-like files and reruns LaTeX and friends until they are stable...

Comment: ... `rerunfilecheck` would be step in the same direction and you could parse its `.log` messages and act accordingly, so I think this would even fit your requirement of being able to continue using makefiles. Just search for `Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File ... has changed. Rerun.`

Comment: I tend to compile all my latex stuff using latexmk, it will automatically pick up changes and compile the required number of times, also picks up when to run, biber, bibtex, make index/xindy, makeglossaries. I usually run it in "deamon" mode, thus once I save a file it compiles automatically.

Comment: IMO makefiles can end up running LaTeX more than you need as you hard code into the file how many times it should run.

Comment: I know the algorithm latexmk uses is based on finding all the files the project depends on, and then keeping an eye on them (based on both timestamps, hash value and analysis). It is not as easy as just a simple if then else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just collecting my comments into an answer.

Straightforward `.log` file parsing can not be guaranteed to be sufficient to detect necessary reruns. The rerun warnings in the `.log` only appear because LaTeX has set up a heuristic to warn you if `\labels` and citations (and maybe a few other things) look as though they need another LaTeX run. But packages are not obliged to use those monitored mechanisms and may well do their own thing.

The code in the question is a prime example of such code. The relevant labels are written out with the custom `\Newlabel` command (instead of `\newlabel`) and there is no code to detect changes with those.

Indeed the only relevant differences between the `.log` files of the first and second run are

```
No file <jobname>.aux.
```

vs

```
(<jobname>.aux)
```

and whether or not a file called `<jobname>.spl` is loaded.

It is now easy to construct an example where the `.log` files remains the same (except for time and memory information), but the output still needs another LaTeX run.

1. Take the example from the question and compile it twice.
2. Add a third author: `\author[3]{Antonín Dvořák}` with address `\address[3]{Vyšehrader Friedhof}`
3. Compile *once* to see the footnote "1" for Dvořák.
4. Compile again to get "*c*".

In between steps 3 and 4 the `.log` file stays the same except for date/time info, memory usage and line numbers for the font infos. None of these changes, however, indicates that another LaTeX run is necessary.

So unless the packages you use have some kind of heuristics built in on the LaTeX side that double-checks if a rerun is needed and warns in the `.log`, the `.log` file alone is not enough to decide whether to rerun LaTeX.

That is one of the reasons why `latexmk` also monitors the auxiliary files for changes. If the auxiliary files are stable between runs it stands to reason that the output should also be stable. Indeed, in the example above `\Newlabel{3}{c}` gets added to the `.aux` file in the LaTeX run of step 3. So the `.aux` is different before and after the run in step 3, but the run in step 4 does not change the `.aux` file. (Of course there are situations where a rerun is not needed even if the `.aux` files change, for example because new `\label`s are not used. So it is not guaranteed that the resulting build cycle is the shortest for a given document. Additionally, there are situations where the `.aux` file never stabilises: [Avoid infinite compiler passes with biblatex ibid citation styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81695/35864).)

The package `rerunfilecheck`, which you mention in the question, makes it possible to monitor the `.aux` file between LaTeX runs. In particular the hash of the `.aux` file before and after the current LaTeX run are compared. If the hash changed, that indicates that a rerun might be useful and you get a warning of the following form

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `<jobname>.aux' has changed. Rerun.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `<jobname>.aux':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: AE406B0DDBF18055292F1343793AC8CB;63
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  ED9C2E0E40AE4680FD0E58AB745EA3BF;80.
```

If, on the other hand, the `.aux` is stable, it reports

```
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `<jobname>.aux' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: ED9C2E0E40AE4680FD0E58AB745EA3BF;80.
```

So with `rerunfilecheck` your task just reduces to parsing the rerun warnings of that package.

It might be possible to redo what `rerunfilecheck` does externally in your makefile.

- Hash the current `.aux` and remember the hash.
- Run LaTeX.
- Hash the new `.aux` and compare to the old hash.
- If the hashes are different, rerun.

I doubt that it would be worth the effort, but it might be a nice academic exercise in bash scripting (not that I have any idea how to go about actually achieving this task).