# Understanding how references and labels work

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm trying to understand why I cannot effectively reference figures or equations that I have defined with labels.

For example:

```
\begin{figure}
  \label{fig:area_Treasuries}
  \caption{Treasuries as a portion of total financial flows.}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{graphs/Area_Treasuries.png}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{}
Figure~\ref{fig:area_Treasuries} presents Treasuries (both flowing
into and out of the United States) as a share of total financial
flows.  From 1985 to 2010, Treasuries account for, on average, 53.2\%
of total financial flows.
```

With the above code, I get this warning:

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:area_Treasuries' on page 37 undefined on
>   input line 477.

The result is "Figure ?? presents Treasuries..."

Why is this happening?  Related, I don't understand why I can't reference, say, an equation before (I mean physically above in the text) the actual equation.  Isn't this what compiling multiple times and cross references is supposed to take care of?

Comment: What documentation on `\caption` and `\label` did you read?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

There are a number of things to take into account when considering using the `\label`-`\ref` system. For many, this comes naturally, but once you understand it, it should help out with most of your problems.

---

### 1. Placement of `\label`

Yes, this is important. Why? Well, `\label` is defined in the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) as

```
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

Note that (despite all the other things going on), it writes to the `.aux` file something that looks like this:

```
\newlabel{<label>}{{<currentlabel>}{<page>}}
```

where `<label>` is what supply in the form `\label{<label>}` and `<currentlabel>` is the current value of `\@currentlabel` - a macro that is usually updated whenever you call `\refstepcounter{<cntr>}`. So, if `\@currentlabel` is not up-to-date according to the reference you're after, then you'll obtain an incorrect reference. Most notably this happens when you place a `\label` *before* `\caption`, since `\caption` increases some counter (`figure` or `table` counter, say). `<page>` is the page on which the reference occurs within the document and has the value of `\thepage` at that time - this could be anything set out in the definition of `\thepage`, just for clarity.

Bottom line: Since `\label` uses `\@currentlabel`, make sure your placement of `\label` is *after* an update of it. In some cases you can get away with it, since the counter update happens at the beginning of an environment (like in theorems, usually), or the environment is written in such a way to capture and properly allocate a `\label` to a counter through multiple passes, or just a regular collection process.

Some people try and avoid this confusion of `\label` placement by placing `\label` *inside* a float `\caption` (say). This is perfectly okay since the counter associated with printing the caption is updated *before* the caption (and the included `\label`) is set.

Related reference: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)

---

### 2. How many times do I have to compile?

In general, the `\label`-`\ref` system works as a two-phase process, and therefore requires at least two compiles (during a first iteration, possibly fewer in subsequent compiles). During the first `\label` phase, a label is written to the `.aux` file in the form (assuming you don't load any cross-referencing package like [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)):

```
\newlabel{<label>}{{<reference>}{<page>}
```

Here's a practical example and the output after a single compile:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
See Section~\ref{sec:section}.
\end{document}
```

In particular, the above MWE produces the following `.aux`:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}A section}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:section}{{1}{1}}
```

that, in addition to possible ToC-related content, contains the appropriate `\newlabel`. The reference itself still shows up as `??`, since it was not known what the reference was at the time of writing that content. To understand this a little better, you should know that the `.aux` file is actually read just before `\begin{document}`. So, during the first compile, at the time TeX reads `\ref{<label>}`, the `.aux` file did not contain any reference information, and therefore `\ref` leads to `??` as output.

Now, during a subsequent compile, the `.aux` is read at `\begin{document}` and therefore associates a reference (and the appropriate page number) with a specific label. As such, when `\ref{<label>}` is encountered (during the second phase), it can produce the correct reference.

Sure, you don't *always* need two compiles to obtain the correct reference. This is because no change in a label's location on a specific page would not yield any different output and therefore not require any additional "pair-wise" compilations.

---

### 3. So what happens in the `.aux` file?

As already explained, whenever you write `\label{<label>}`, the `.aux` gets written with

```
\newlabel{<label>}{{<reference>}{<page>}}
```

at page shipout. However, this information is read and executed at `\begin{document}` during subsequent compiles. And, from a technical perspective (if you investigate the role of `\newlabel` and friends in the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)) `\label{<label>}` creates a macro by the name of `\r@<label>` that expands to `{<reference>}{<page>}`. And depending on whether you use `\ref{<label>}` or `\pageref{<label>}`, you'll either be receiving `<reference>` (technically, `\@firstoftwo`) or `<page>` (technically, `\@secondoftwo`).

---

### 4. What's with the page reference?

Whenever you use `\label`, writing of this information to the `.aux` is actually delayed until page shipout. The reason for this is because the system is set up that way so that a single `<label>` can be used to reference the `<label>` "title" (usually in the form of a number) as well as the location (page) within the document. Since TeX asynchronously collects and optimizes page content, it could be that an already-read `\label` has to wait for a subsequent page to be written. Therefore, not waiting until page shipout may imply an incorrect page number to be associated with the reference.

This is usually also a reason why there is such confusion between having to compile twice, or three times, or perhaps more. The truth behind this is that you have to compile as many times as possible until the references settle (that is, no change in page number or label for a reference change). The magic number is usually two, but it could be more.

For an example of pushing the envelope, see [Document requiring infinitely many compiler passes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30674/5764).

---

### 5. Packages that influence the regular `\label`-`\ref` system

There are many packages that influence the way `\label` and `\ref` work. Most notably is [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), since it allows for integration with the default `\label`-`\ref` interface, yet adds some additional information beyond the default reference and page number. In fact, when using `hyperref` with the above MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
See Section~\ref{sec:section}.
\end{document}
```

the `.aux` resembles

```
\relax 
% ... some hyperref stuff
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}A section}{1}{section.1}}
\newlabel{sec:section}{{1}{1}{A section}{section.1}{}}
```

Note how `\newlabel` still has the same two-argument format. However, the second argument now contains 5 groups `{..}` compared to the original non-`hyperref` two. The first two are inherited from the original system, while the last three are new. The third contains the title associated with the specific reference (in this case, a section, so the section title). The fourth is a counter-specific reference, used in the hyper-linking process, while the fifth is always empty (perhaps meant for later expansion of the package itself, and therefore just safe-keeping).

---

### 6. Packages that extend the regular `\label`-`\ref` system

Here are some packages that extend LaTeX's cross-referencing capabilities:

- `hyperref`

It allows you to include the named title of the reference (mainly as a result of including [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)). Additionally it provides the option of "auto referencing" an label - using `\autoref` - which inserts a prefix that is typically added manually (therefore turning `see \autoref{<label>}` into `see Figure~\ref{<label>}`, say).

- [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)

All regular `\label`s store only two values: the current label and the page number where that label exists (see `\newlabel` above). `zref` extends this in a natural way to allow for any number of such stored *properties* through what it calls a "property list". This property list is akin to a key-value interface, but using macros and has the form

```
    \z@newlabel{<label>}{\propA{<propA>}\propB{<propB>}...}
```

Note the `\z@`-prefix, making it obviously different from the traditional `\newlabel`. In fact, you can still use `\label`-`\ref` when using `zref`, or use the `zref`-specific `\zlabel`-`\zref`. Of course, more complex labelling/referencing exist; see the [`zref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/zref.pdf) for more details.

---

Specific to your case:

- You have `\label` *before* `\caption` - a very common problem. As such, `\@currentlabel` does not contain the up-to-date information you require, and would return an incorrect reference. See **1** above in terms of the `\label` placement.
- As a first run, you need to compile at least twice in order for the references to settle. See **2** above in terms of the number of compilations.
- You *can* reference an equation (or anything) before it actually occurs within the text. That's the beauty of TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system; that it uses an external file (`.aux`) as the go-between for writing content about the reference, as well as the location of loading the external file. So, you can most certainly do the following

  ```
    %...
    ... see equation~\ref{eqn:myeqn} below:
    \begin{equation}
      f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:myeqn}
    \end{equation}
    %...
  ```

...just as long as you compile at least twice in the first go. See **2** in terms of the number of compilations.

Comment: a lot i have learnt from this answer. but i think this is a bit hard for first reading

Comment: @zongpingding: Like the `\label`\-`\ref` system, just read it twice. :)

Answer (score 40):

The label for an object must be *after* that object is defined.  So if you are labeling a caption (which you are in your example) the `\label` command must follow the caption or be part of it.  So instead of

```
\label{fig:area_Treasuries}
\caption{Treasuries as a portion of total financial flows.}
```

You should use:

```
\caption{Treasuries as a portion of total financial flows.}   
\label{fig:area_Treasuries}
```

or

```
 \caption{Treasuries as a portion of total financial flows.\label{fig:area_Treasuries}}
```