# Cleveref reference table as section

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, cleveref, sections-paragraphs

I am using `cleveref` for my references, and I just noticed that a reference to a table is actually resolved by `cleveref` into “section”. Is that indended behaviour? Is there maybe something wrong with my `TeXLive`? This looks very odd to me:
[image: Very messed up references.]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Top section}
\subsection{Lower section}\label{sec:lower}
This is a reference to my \cref{tab:test} and to my \cref{sec:lower}.
Also, a reference to a second \cref{tab:test2}

\begin{table}[hbtp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    Case          & One \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:test}
  \caption{This is a table.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbtp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    Case          & One \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:test2}
  \caption{This is a table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\label` *after* `\caption`.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325) or [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280) Let us know- we could then close this as a duplicate if you agree :)

Comment: Hilarious. I have actually searched for all sorts of combinations about cleveref, tables, sections, you name it. I wouldn't have for the life of me thought about the order of label and caption. Thanks a lot for the very quick help! Ah, and of course you are free to close this. ;)