# Labels do not increment

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, cross-referencing, numbering

In my document, I have a lot of short case studies, which I would like to number, just like figures. So I am using this:

```
\subsubsection{Case study \ref{cs:this}: Title}
\begin{figure}
\label{cs:this} 
\end{figure}
```

But this just copies the (sub)section number in the reference. So I have multple "1.1" case studies, etc... I would like them to be numbered X.Y, where X is the section number and Y is the case study number. So for example, in section 1, I would have case studies 1.1-1.10, in section 2 case studies 2.1-2.7, etc... Those case studies can be a part of section or subsection. My secnumdepth is 2.

And later I would like to have a list of case studies, where I would include all figures with labels beginning with `cs:`. Is that possible as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `\caption` in order to increment the `figure`/float counter. See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

Instead, make yourself a new `casestudy` float:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/casestudy

% New casestudy float
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{casestudy}{htbp}{loc}[section]
\renewcommand{\thecasestudy}{\thesection.\arabic{casestudy}}
\floatname{casestudy}{Case Study}
\newcommand*{\listofcasestudies}{\listof{casestudy}{List of Case Studies}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofcasestudies
\section{Case study~\ref{cs:this}: Title}
\begin{casestudy}
\caption{A case study}
\label{cs:this}
\end{casestudy}
\end{document}
```

This is fully supported by the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: Is there a way to not include the caption in the text? This way I end up with heading AND caption.

Comment: @JakubZaverka It seems to me that you don't want a floating environment at all. So using `\subsubsection`, `figure` and `\newfloat` seems to be a wrong approach, you should define your own counter (using `\newcounter` and `\refstepcounter`) and your own commands (or environment) instead.