# Referencing an environment before it is labelled

Tags: hyperref

Using the package hyperref I'm noticing that I can't reference things properly. It seems that \autoref actually references the latest section, table, equation or figure (in short environment) before a label. Is this right? and what am I doing wrong?

```
\subsection{One one}

I want to write: `\autoref{tab:one}' shows such and such:

\begin{table}
    \caption{some bumpf}
    \label{tab:one}
\end{table}
```

Gives me: I want to write subsection 1.1 shows such and such.

**EDIT**

I have caption I forgot it in this instance. The question I'm asking is why my reference is to something that is not labelled? Eg, why do I get a reference to a subsection if the label is clearly in the figure environment or table environment?  Is it really always because I may have forgotten the order of label after caption somewhere?

Comment: You need a caption in the `table` environment for the label to get a sensible value. So `\caption{<text of the caption>}\label{tab:one}`

Comment: You've gotten your answer, so for reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111280/understanding-how-references-and-labels-work and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption

Comment: The caption didn't "warn" the label that there is a table waiting for labelling, so instead it got stuck to the last labellable thing it saw: the subsection. It is really oversimplifying, but you shouldn't think about it too much anyway: the behavior of a label before its caption is unspecified, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `\caption{...}` before the `\label`:

```
\subsection{One one}

I want to write: `\autoref{tab:one}' shows such and such:

\begin{table}
    \caption{Some Table}
    \label{tab:one}
\end{table}
```

[image]