# How can I label an interlinear gloss in gb4e?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I'd like to refer to interlinear glosses within a text. I tried putting a label beneath the `\begin{exe}` line (as below) to but it didn't work. How would I be able to fix this? Are there helpful articles that I can read/skim that refer to this kind of reference?

```
In \ref{1e1} we can see something hilarious.


\begin{exe}
\label{1e1}
\ex 
\glll   Zuqaza  uba movb    sovawdam ubat   law apt'aniwdam sas. \\
\{zuqaza    uba movb(a)-\textbf{_{c}$\oslash$}  sova-wda-m(a) uba-t(a)    law(a)-_{c}$\oslash$  ap(a)-t'a-ni-wda-m(a)   sa.s(a)\} \\
boy that    town-\textsc{acc}   go-\textsc{bfr-2imp} that-\textsc{abl}  wood-\textsc{acc}   tabe-\textsc{m-h-bfr-2imp}  think \\
\glt    `Go to that town, boy and then bring some wood.' [EBF4.40B]
\end{exe}
```

Comment: *Please* ask questions with example documents. Since the interlinear gloss line isn't numbered, what would you expect the reference to look like?  You can refer to whole examples or subparts of examples within an `xlist` using the regular `\label`, `\ref` commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will reiterate our plea to ask questions with *complete* minimal documents rather than code fragments. This makes it clear what the problem is, and allows people to help you faster.

The issue you are having is a common one with `\label` and `\ref` commands.  The rule of thumb is that the thing that is labeled must *follow* the element that introduces the number.  See the following for a great discussion of this:

- [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/2693)

In `gb4e` the `\ex` command introduces the number (or letter within an `xlist`) and you need to put the \label command after the example (right before `\end{exe}` in a single part example.) This has nothing to do with interlinear glosses, so your question title is very unclear.

Here is a minimal working example of the solution.  In the future you should post documents like this one in your questions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

In (\ref{1e1}) we can see something hilarious.

\begin{exe}
\ex 
\glll   Zuqaza  uba movb    sovawdam ubat   law apt'aniwdam sas. \\
\{zuqaza    uba movb(a)-\textbf{_{c}$\oslash$}  sova-wda-m(a) uba-t(a)    law(a)-_{c}$\oslash$  ap(a)-t'a-ni-wda-m(a)   sa.s(a)\} \\
boy that    town-\textsc{acc}   go-\textsc{bfr-2imp} that-\textsc{abl}  wood-\textsc{acc}   tabe-\textsc{m-h-bfr-2imp}  think \\
\glt    `Go to that town, boy and then bring some wood.' [EBF4.40B]
\label{1e1} % label goes *after* the \ex
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

If you have a multipart example, using `gb4e`'s `xlist` environment, then the `\label` for the whole set of examples goes after the initial `\ex`:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{mylabel}
\begin{xlist}
\ex
\ex
...
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
```