# How can I label a numbered interlinear gloss in gb4e?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I'd like to refer to interlinear glosses within a text. I tried putting a label beneath the \begin{exe} line (as below) to but it didn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

```
In \ref{1e1} we can see something hilarious.

\begin{exe} \label{1e1} \ex \glll Zuqaza uba movb sovawdam ubat law apt'aniwdam sas. \ 
{zuqaza uba movb(a)-\textbf{{c}$\oslash$} sova-wda-m(a) uba-t(a) law(a)-{c}$\oslash$ ap(a)-t'a-ni-wda-m(a) sa.s(a)} \ 
boy that town-\textsc{acc} go-\textsc{bfr-2imp} that-\textsc{abl} wood-\textsc{acc} tabe-\textsc{m-h-bfr-2imp} think \ 
\glt `Go to that town, boy and then bring some wood.' [EBF4.40B] \end{exe}
```

linguistics

Comment: You should clarify the closed question, and we might reopen it.  But I think most of your problem can be solved by reading this: [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280).  You need to put the label *after* the thing that it labels. In `\gb4e` the `\ex` command introduces the number (or letter within an `xlist`) and you need to put the `\label` command after the example (right before `\end{exe}` in a single part example.) This has nothing to do with interlinear glosses, so your previous question was very unclear, which is why we closed it.

Comment: Mateuz, people have been very patient in answering your questions so far, but we've also asked you to put a bit more work into asking them by providing complete minimal documents that show the problem you're having. If you continue to ask questions without code or just with a code fragment (as you did here and your previous question) this patience will soon wear out, and more of your questions will end up being closed as "not real questions".