# Why does ref link to section instead of label?

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing

I want to refer to a figure within a section (say 1.2), using `\ref{fig:xyz}`

Section:

```
\section{XYZ}
```

Figure:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{xyz.jpg}
    \label{fig:xyz}
    \caption[XYZ]
\end{figure}
```

When I add \ref{label:001} to my document, it does not link to the figure, but to the section (1.2).

What can I get it right?

Comment: The most F asked question of all. \label has to be after (or in) \caption

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I could not find it here, that's why I added it.

Comment: searching for figure section \label on this site shows lots of duplicates (and lots more that have been closed already as duplicates)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that is a possible duplicate. However, I could not find it using the keywords that were relevant for me, `ref`, `label` and `section`. Maybe my question is a good addition, maybe not.

Comment: I think it would be better to edit or re-tag the duplicate rather than create a new question.

Comment: @PaulStanley I would be totally fine with that as well. But I really could not find anything on the problem, so I opened a new one. Sorry!

Comment: @Martin Betz I wasn't being critical: it certainly makes sense to make such a basic point easily "findable"; just trying to explain why I was going to vote to close.

Comment: @PaulStanley Totally understand that! Let's see what the others think. I was just thinking about how I could do it differently next time. Probably have to extend my search and specificly look for possible duplicates...

Comment: Another really helpful duplicate is: [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)

Answer (score 16):

You have to put `\label` after `\caption` - and everything will work.

```
Thus, your figure will now be:
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{xyz.jpg}
    \caption[XYZ]
    \label{fig:xyz}
\end{figure}
```