# section numbering wrong

Tags: numbering

ok heres the re edit

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\closure}[2][3]{%
  {}\mkern#1mu\overline{\mkern-#1mu#2}}
  \begin{document}
  \section{Schwarzschild Manifold as a Graph}
\begin{definition}
Let $m\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $m>0$ and consider the manifold
\begin{align*}
S=\left\{(r,x)|(r,x)\in{(2m,\infty){\times}S^2} \right\}.
\end{align*}
Now equip $S$ with the Riemannian metric
\begin{align*}
g_S=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2m}{r}}dr^2+r^2d{\theta}^2+r^2{\sin\theta}^2d{\phi}^2,
\end{align*}
where $(\theta,{\phi})$ are the standard polar coordinates on $S^2$. Then we call $(S,g_S)$ the Schwarzschild manifold.
\end{definition}

  \begin{chapter}
{The Positive Mass Theorem for Graphs over $\mathbb{R}^3$}
\begin{theorem}\label{positivemasstheorem}
{\textnormal{(Positive Mass Theorem for graphs over $\mathbb{R}^3$)}} 
\begin{equation}{\label{positivemassthmeqn}}
 m_{ADM}=\frac{1}{16\pi}\int_MR\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}\,dV_g.
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{chapter}
\end{document}
```

i get the first section as 0.1, first defn as 0.1.1 which is okay. but when the new chapter stats, the theorem starts as 0.1.2?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can highlight code by selecting it and clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field. See our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for more information on how the site works.

Comment: You have a misplaced label.  See [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)

Comment: even when i remove the label it doesnt work. its carrying on the numbers from the last section of the last chapter, but i definetly ended both of them. also, if i start a new section after the chapter, it all works fine. but i dont want to have a section there?

Comment: `\section` is renumbered from zero when the chapter changes, but `\subsection` isn't -- it resets at each `\section`.  so at the chapter break, `\setcounter{subsection}{0}` explicitly.

Comment: Please make a complete (small) document that shows the probem: remove any text that you can remove while still showing the problem. (You will probably solve it yourself while trying to make this file:-) note it is very unusual to have 0 at all `4.0.1` is very strange numbering to get from a report class document.

Comment: ah @barbarabeeton no doubt has it, but better would be to use `\section` rather than `\subsection`

Comment: its still not working, even after the setcounter

Comment: ok i did it, but using \setcounter{theorem}{0}. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`amsthm` sets counters for theorems and friends with a mechanism essentially the same as used for `\numberwithin`.  if the command used for the numbering of a counter isn't preceded by the "within" element, the affected counter isn't reset.  this reset then has to be done explicitly.

in this case, there is no `\section` preceding the `theorem` that begins the chapter, so it's necessary, after the chapter is invoked, to reset the `theorem` counter:

```
\setcounter{theorem}{0}
```

by the way, it's not recommended to use `\begin{chapter} ... \end{chapter}`.  just `\chapter{...}` is preferable.