# Reference to a listing returns wrong number

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I'm using the following code to create a listing with sourcecode:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={caption_text}\label{lst:a_label},language=Java] 
// Code...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Unfortunately, a `\ref{lst:a_label}` somewhere in my text does not return the correct number, or at least not the number I expected. The caption itself shows the correct number. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try putting the `\label` inside the caption.  See [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280) for some good discussion.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I think the `lstlisting` environment prefers the label to be inserted as a normal parameter:

Adapt the following code to your needs and see if you obtain what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some Java code},label={lst:label},language=Java]
// Code...
\end{lstlisting}
See code~\ref{lst:label}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that in the `lstlisting` declaration you should use `label={example}` instead of `\label{example}`.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}, caption={example is here}, label={example}]
```

Adding a label e.g., `{lst:test}` to the parameters of `lstlisting` works too if you call a script externally e.g., `{test.py}` as opposed to using a `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}` block as shown below:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, caption=Example, label={lst:test}]{test.py}
```

Comment: Welcome, this was already covered in the accepted answer.

Comment: I think it is not very clear where there was the error. That's why I answered it :)