# Shortcut for listinputlisting reference

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I would like to know if it is possible to set up a command such that when the `\ref` of the Matlab `\lstinputlisting` is called, that the words "Matlab Algorithm X.X" itself becomes a hyperref link and also colored blue instead of having to type the command `{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Matlab Algorithm \ref{XX}}}}` each time?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,
            colorlinks = true,
            backref=true,
            pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = mybluei,
            linkcolor = .,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Matlab Algorithm}}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{filecontents}{mat1.m}
% arm1
x1 = [0 0]; y1 = [0 1];
x2 = [0 1]; y2 = [1 1];
x3 = [1 1]; y3 = [1 2];

% Size figure and draw arms
figure('position', [800, 300, 600, 550]);
hold on
plot(xcirc, ycirc,'m','linewidth', 1);
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily\small,
caption={Draw a simple Fig.}
]{mat1.m}\label{mat1}

In the {\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Matlab Algorithm \ref{mat1}}}} code generate above in  we see how the arm moves.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Package `cleveref`, I would say!

Comment: In your example code, I can't get the `\ref` to point at the listing unless I move the label into the caption, e.g. `caption={Draw a simple Fig.\label{mat1}}`. See also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122287/55879).

Comment: @ArunDebray: There's a `label=...` option in `listings` as well -- the O.P. missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `cleveref`, you can just define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\matref}[1]{%
    \hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{blue}Matlab Algorithm \ref{#1}}}%
}
```

Then, use `\matref{label}` instead of `\ref{label}` to refer to your Matlab code.

Answer (score 2):

This uses `cleveref` and its `\crefformat` macros for the `listing` counter, however, this will be applied for any listing if used together with `\cref` or `\Cref`.

The format has to be in the order `#2 Some text #1#3` to make hyperlinks correct.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,
            colorlinks = true,
            backref=true,
            pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = mybluei,
            linkcolor = .,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Matlab Algorithm}}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}

\crefname{listing}{matlab algorithm}{matlab algorithms}
\Crefname{listing}{Matlab Algorithm}{Matlab algorithms}

\crefformat{listing}{{\bfseries \color{blue}#2matlab algorithm~#1#3}}
\Crefformat{listing}{{\bfseries \color{blue}#2Matlab algorithm~#1#3}}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{filecontents}{mat1.m}
% arm1
x1 = [0 0]; y1 = [0 1];
x2 = [0 1]; y2 = [1 1];
x3 = [1 1]; y3 = [1 2];

% Size figure and draw arms
figure('position', [800, 300, 600, 550]);
hold on
plot(xcirc, ycirc,'m','linewidth', 1);
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily\small,
caption={Draw a simple Fig.},
label={mat1}
]{mat1.m}

\clearpage
In the \Cref{mat1} code generate above in  we see how the arm moves and in \cref{mat1} we see the same!

In the {\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Matlab Algorithm \ref{mat1}}}} code generate above in  we see how the arm moves.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!  Just out of curiosity, from your comment, if I then wanted to add, let's say a Python listing, (together with this Matlab listing), I would have a problem with the Python listing then?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, unless the listings package does allow specifying another counter. Have a look into the `marvellous `tcolorbox` package which uses `listings` in the background and extends the typesetting definitely

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer, on a side note, I wanted to tell you "Thanks" for basically setting me on the right path to post questions in a manner that conforms with the forum's protocol.  I think since then, I have been making it somewhat easier for the professionals (like yourself) to answer my questions in a timely manner.  Thanks again!