# How to customize cross-reference numbering of custom environments?

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, counters

**Context:** I have several environments with custom counters. As usual, I'm referencing them along to my document but I get only the corresponding counter value as reference.

**Example:**

```
\newcounter{myenvcounter}[section]\setcounter{myenvcounter}{0}
\def\theenv{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{myenvcounter}}
\newenvironment{myenv}{
    \refstepcounter{myenvcounter}%
\\
    \noindent\textbf{Env. \theenv{}.}%
}{%
   \\
}
```

An instance of this environment:

```
\chapter{Chapter one} \label{ch:one}
   ...
   \section{Section one} \label{sec:one}
      ...
      \begin{myenv} \label{env:one} 
         Bla bla bla.
      \end{myenv}
      ... \\
      As shown in Env. \ref{env:one} ... etc.
```

And this produces:

---

**1 Chapter one**

...

**1.1 Section one**

...

**Env. 1.1.1.** Bla bla bla.

...

As shown in Env. 1 ... etc.

---

**Question:** How to customize the cross-reference numbering to get for example: "As shown in Env. 1.1.1" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using

```
\def\theenv{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{myenvcounter}}
```

use

```
\renewcommand{\themyenvcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{myenvcounter}}
```

with a definition of your environment resembling:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \refstepcounter{myenvcounter}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Env.\ \themyenvcounter.}%
}{%
  \par\medskip\ignorespacesafterend%
}
```

The above assumes that `\thesection` is defined to be its usual definition (`\thechapter.\arabic{section}`).

There are two differences:

1. I've used the counter representation of the counter that is actually incremented. That is how referencing of the labels work when using `\refstepcounter` (see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)).
2. Instead of using `\\` for inserting vertical space, I've used `\par\medskip` which sets the environment as a paragraph on its own.

Here is an actual MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{myenvcounter}[section]%
\renewcommand{\themyenvcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{myenvcounter}}
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \refstepcounter{myenvcounter}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Env.\ \themyenvcounter.}%
}{%
  \par\medskip\ignorespacesafterend%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one} \label{ch:one}
Some text...
\section{Section one} \label{sec:one}
Some text
\begin{myenv} \label{env:one} 
Bla bla bla.
\end{myenv}
As shown in Env.~\ref{env:one} \ldots\ etc.
\end{document}
```