# PDF Latex lastpage does not work

Tags: cross-referencing, lastpage

I've added the last page package tried to display the pager but the last page wont display.
What's wrong with my code, the last page will just display a "??":

```
{.select date_format(now()," %M %d, %Y %r") as  run_date}
{.select username from deskpad.user where user_id=@user_teller}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,margin=0.1in,headheight=0.5in,footskip=0.4in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[l]{
}
\fancyfoot[l]{
\small{
\begin{tabular}{p{4.0in} p{4.0in}}
\hspace{15pt} \small{ \emph{ Date Printed: {.\run_date\} } } & \raggedleft{ \small{ \emph{ Page \thepage\ of \pageref{Last Page} } } \hspace{15pt}} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct key is `\pageref{LastPage}`, without spaces. Two LaTeX runs are necessary for getting the correct reference when the number of pages changes: on the first run the value is written in the `.aux` file and read back in in the following run.

---

Here's also a better way to achieve the same result for the footer, using the `L` and `R` fields without any guess about the widths.

Note that `fancyheadings` is obsolete and should not be loaded, `fancyhdr` is sufficient.

I omitted also the packages not necessary for the example; the `kantlipsum` package is just to provide the `\kant` command that produces mock text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=11in,
  paperwidth=8.5in,
  margin=0.1in,
  headheight=0.5in,
  footskip=0.4in,
  includehead,
  includefoot
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \small\hspace{15pt}\emph{Date Printed: \today}%
}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
  \small\emph{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}\hspace{15pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need `\pageref{LastPage}`, since the label is `LastPage`, not `Last Page`. You may also have to compile your document at least twice (as a start), in order for the reference to show up correctly. See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

Comment: still not displaying....I just learned that it's normal. Needs to be compiled twice to complete the document.