# LaTeX is confusing subsections and figures

Tags: cross-referencing

So I have a section of code that looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\label{collecting_the_spectra}
\subsection{}
\label{usb}
If the screen in Figure \ref{4_specs} 

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5in]{4_specs.png}
\hspace{1.5in}\parbox{5in}{\caption{All spectrometers.}}
\label{4_specs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and should compile if you point `4_specs.png` at an actual picture but for some reason it outputs stuff like this

[image]

Notice the spots where it says "Figure 0.1".  No where else is a label made called `4_specs`.  Those are the only references broken in the entire paper.  Why is LaTeX doing this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a frequent mistake: the `label` needs to go *after* your `caption`. It takes a lot to confuse `LaTeX` :)

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you for your quick response, but that is actually the way I originally had it.  I just switched it back and the error persists.

Comment: You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to help us diagnose the issue

Comment: Don't put your caption inside a `\parbox`... Not sure why you do that in the first place. Can you explain?

Comment: @Werner Well you are correct in why it was not working, however I was using a \parbox because my caption is really long and is too wide when compared to both my figure and paragraph beneath it.  Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: Nevermind, the solution is to put the \label in the \parbox after the \caption .  Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: On another note: It is not a good idea to have very long captions (it disturbs the reading); give the long explanation outside the caption and then have a short one in it.

Answer (score 5):

The following MWE replicates your problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
See Figures~\ref{fig:A} and~\ref{fig:B}.
\begin{figure}
  % <your figure>
  \caption{A caption}\label{fig:A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  % <your figure>
  {\caption{A caption}}\label{fig:B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that Figure 2 has its caption placed inside a group `{`...`}`. That similar to putting a `\caption` inside a `\parbox`. When you issue a `\label`, LaTeX updates a macro called `\@currentlabel` that contains the last-updated counter. After a group is closed, macro-updates contained within are usually restored, leaving the reference to be incorrect. For a general discussion regarding the `\label`-`\ref` system, see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

If the motivation for setting the `\caption` in a `\parbox` is to fix the width, consider using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) instead. It provides a `width` key-value that may provide exactly what you're after (see section **2.4 Margins and further paragraph options**, p 11 or the [`caption` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf)). Of course, it also provides a host of other functionality.

Here is a `caption`-approach to the MWE:

```
\begin{figure}
  % <your figure>
  \captionsetup{width=<len>}% Constrain caption width to <len>
  \caption{<your caption>}\label{fig:B}
\end{figure}
```

Or you could set the key-values globally in your document preamble.