# How to number figures continuously in documentclass{article}

Tags: numbering

Currently my document labels figures in a continuous manner (figure 1, figure 2, etc.) but references to these same figures have the section, subsection, etc. number in front of it (3.1.1 for a figure in the 3rd section and 1st subsection).  I want the references to my figures to number in the same continuous fashion as the figures themselves (i.e. figure 1, figure 2, no matter what section the figures are in). I tried using `\counterwithout{figure}{section}` and `\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}` but the 3.1.1 style of figure referencing continues.

Here is a minimum working example that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}

\usepackage{graphicx}               

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}

Figure~\ref{fig:foo}
\begin{figure}
\label{fig:foo}
\includegraphics[width=6in]{foo.ps}
\caption{sample text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the following posts: [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764); [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `article` that's the default behaviour, so you don't have to do anything special. In your case you experienced an odd result because you were misplacing `\label`. Always put `\label` *after* `\caption` in floats (or, inside `\caption`, but never before it.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}               

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}

Figure~\ref{fig:foo}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics[width=6in]{foo.ps}
\caption{sample text}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The number you are getting is the number of the subsection; you used `\label` before `\caption`, so the last anchor (the one of the subsection) was picked to generate the cross-reference.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: You could also place the `\label` macro inside the `\caption` macro. That removes having to remember which order they go in.

Comment: @MikeRenfro true. I've added this remark. Thanks.