# Numbering chapters, sections and subsections continuous after figure label, not the document

Tags: floats, numbering

I have problem with numbering subsection after figure label.
I put appendix, caption and label, and put counter of figure to 0 so graph label says Picture 1. Then, when i want to start new chapter, section or subsection, it is numbered .0.1. instead of example, 2.2.1. How do i end figure labeling and let document continue section numbering normally? Here is the code:

```
\section{text}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\appendix

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y,grid=both,xmax=10,ymax=10,axis lines=middle,restrict y to domain=-7:10,enlargelimits]
\addplot[blue]  {pow(2,x)} node[above]{$y=2^x$};
\addplot[red]  {pow(10,x)} node[above]{$y=10^x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\caption{text}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure}

\subsection{text}
```

Comment: What is your over all goal doing this? Why is there an `\appendix`-Tag in the middle of your figure?

Comment: @nhck I have a section 2.2. In there i need to put a graph of an exponential function. This is my first picture in document so i need to label it: "Picture 1: Exponential graph". If i just use caption and label, it's label isn't "1." but "2.1" for some reason. If i put \appendix and set counter to 0, it shows correct number of caption but messes up section numbering. It may be a minor problem, i just started working in tex yesterday, so I only put appendix in because it worked that way, I cant really understand what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbering depends on your documentclass. I'm assuming book in this example. You can use the package [chngcntr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) to adjust the figure numbering to include or exclude certain numbers. The example below excludes section and subsection number for the figure number.

The `\appendix`tag you use is just for resetting the counter to start the appendix numbering.

These two posts are also a good read for you:
[How to number figures continuously in documentclass{article}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160540/140011) and
[Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/140011)

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum} %Just for the sampletext


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %Package for the Figures

\usepackage{chngcntr} %Package to set the counter
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}


\begin{document}
\chapter{This is Chapter}
\section{Section One}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{img}
    \caption{trest}
    \label{fig:dogemadone}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{img}
    \caption{trest2}
    \label{fig:dogemad}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection of Section Two}
\lipsum[2-4]

\appendix %This changes the counter for the appendix
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum*
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. I deleted appendix and set counter within figure, added \usepackage{chngcntr} and added \counterwithout command.