# Fancyref using wrong table number

Tags: tables, fancyref

I am currently working on my thesis and I discovered a nasty problem. I use the following code to reference a table:

```
\fref{tab:alternatives}
```

Now I defined the table like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|*{10}{c}}
    %removed the content
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:alternatives}
\caption{Comparing functionalities}
\end{table}
```

Now when I generate the pdf fancyref produces the following:
"First in table 2.2"
but the table is called: "Table 2.1.: Comparing functionalities"

How can this be?

Comment: The numbering is done by `\caption`, so the `\label` always has to placed *after* (or within) the `\caption`.

Comment: See [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325) and [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am sorry I didn't find these threads on my own

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake to make, so I knew where to find those questions. Actually, we have a list of questions relating to such common problems (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for pointing out that link. I did not know it