# How to force a label to be a given string?

Tags: cross-referencing

Normally I issue a command like `\label{foo}`, and this means that foo gets entered into a symbol table somewhere that says that it equals 14, or xiv, or aa, or whatever. These symbols are generated and incremented automatically, and to change the numbering system, I can use packages like `alphalph`.

Suppose I want to force foo to evaluate to some arbitrary string, such as "Socrates." E.g., I want something like `\mynameis{Socrates}\label{foo}`, and then when I say `\ref{foo}`, the result will not be "14" but "Socrates."

I want to completely bypass the normal system involving counters. If Socrates is the name of a chapter, then I don't expect LaTeX to be smart enough to automatically name the next chapter Plato. So, e.g.:

```
\chapter{The life of Socrates}\mynameis{Socrates}\label{foo}
...
\chapter{The life of Plato}\label{bar}
...
```

This is an error on my part. It's OK with me if `bar` is set to garbage, or if LaTeX chokes, or if `bar` is set to some arbitrary string such as `Socrates2`.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly easy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mynameis}[1]{#1\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mynameis{Socrates}\label{foo}%

Do you know about \ref{foo}?
\end{document}
```

`\@currentlabel` is the macro that is stored when you use `\label` (in addition to `\thepage`). So, all we do is update this to our liking before calling `\label`.

If you wish for this to be compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you could issue an additional `\phantomsection` so the hyperlink is correct (and perhaps also update `\@currentlabelname`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mynameis}[1]{%
  \phantomsection#1% Mark hyperlink
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabelname}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mynameis{Socrates}\label{foo}%

Do you know about \ref{foo} or \nameref{foo}?
\end{document}
```

For more on cross-referencing, see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).