# Avoiding multiple label-refs in simply-formatted documents

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to build a file with a number of math problems and solutions, like:

> Problems
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
>
> ...
>
> Solutions
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
>
> ...

I want to link back and forth between problems and the corresponding solutions, and vice-versa. In particular, it would be nice to be able to click on the problem number (1., 2., ...) and have it jump to the corresponding solution, and vice-versa.

Is there a way to do this without having to repeatedly type label-ref for every problem and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I define `\addProblemPlusSolution{}{}` for defining problem/solution sets, and then `\showProblemsThenSolutions` to output all the problems sequentially, followed by all of the solutions, with hyperlinked references back and forth.  No `\label`s and `\ref`s are placed explicitly by the user, but are auto-generated by `\showProblemsThenSolutions`.

I don't do anything special in the formatting, other than to create a new `\subsection*` for each problem and solution, respectively.  However, one could add a page break between problems and solutions, additional sectioning, etc.

I use Werner's label solution (the `\mynameis` macro) at [How to force a label to be a given string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175746/how-to-force-a-label-to-be-a-given-string)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mynameis}[1]{%
  \phantomsection#1% Mark hyperlink
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabelname}{#1}}
\makeatother
\newcounter{probcount}
\newcounter{pcindex}
\newcommand\addProblemPlusSolution[2]{%
  \stepcounter{probcount}
  \expandafter\def\csname P\romannumeral\theprobcount\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname S\romannumeral\theprobcount\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand\showProblemsThenSolutions{%
  \setcounter{pcindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\thepcindex < \theprobcount}{%
    \stepcounter{pcindex}%
    \subsection*{\mynameis{Problem \thepcindex}%
                 \label{LP\romannumeral\thepcindex}
                 {\small\mdseries(see \ref{LS\romannumeral\thepcindex})}}

    \csname P\romannumeral\thepcindex\endcsname
  }%
  \setcounter{pcindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\thepcindex < \theprobcount}{%
    \stepcounter{pcindex}%
    \subsection*{\mynameis{Solution \thepcindex}%
                 \label{LS\romannumeral\thepcindex}
                 {\small\mdseries(see \ref{LP\romannumeral\thepcindex})}}

    \csname S\romannumeral\thepcindex\endcsname
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\addProblemPlusSolution
{
  \lipsum[1-3]

  \[ y = mx + b\]
}{
  \[ m = 3, \quad b = 12 \]

  \lipsum[3-4]
}
\addProblemPlusSolution
{
  \lipsum[2-3]

  \[E = mc^2\]
}{
  \[ c = 186,000 \textrm{mi/s} \]

  \lipsum[4]
}

\showProblemsThenSolutions
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]