# Print Solution seperately in exam document class

Tags: exam

I want to print answers separately after the end of the the questions in exam document class. Guide me.

1. Which is/are the neighbouring countries of India?
   A. Nepal  B. USA  C. Thailand  D. China
2. Who introduced mid-meal scheme in Tamil Nadu?
   A. Kamarajar  B. M.G.Ramachandran  C. C.N.Annadurai  D. Thandai Periyar

Solution:
1. (A, D) Hint: Thailand and USA are not neighbouing countries
2. (A) Hint: Kalvikanthiranda Kamarajar.

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237372/answers-at-the-end-of-the-exam-document/