# Solutions on a different page using handout

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, handout

I'm using the following `handout` file:
http://rogercortesi.com/portf/latex/handout.cls

And I realized that when I use the `\showsoln` function, it just shows **SOLUTION** in bold blue letters at the top and bottom. I have narrowed it down to the fact that the .cls file does not contain instructions to display solutions.

His documentation for the `handout` class is in the file directory: http://rogercortesi.com/portf/latex

Is there a way I can fix this, or do you suggest another document class I can use to display solutions on another page? I've looked around on StackExchange, and I haven't found anything that would suit my fairly-beginner knowledge of LaTeX.

Here's what I have, as far as code goes..

```
 \documentclass[soln]{handout}

 \SetInstructor{omitted instructor}
 \SetCourseTitle{omitted course title}
 \SetHandoutTitle{omitted handout title}

 begin{document}
 \maketitle

 \begin{questions}
 \item What is 1+1?
 \soln{1.5in}{\framebox{$2$}.}

 \item What is 2+2?
 \soln{2in}{\framebox{$4$}.}
 \end{questions}
 % Here is where I tried to put \showsoln in. 
 % It worked, but it has the effect I described earlier.
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I use the `exam` class to make handouts but I do not gather solutions at the end. A search of TeX.SE reveals several ways to print solutions at the end, such as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237372/answers-at-the-end-of-the-exam-document).

Comment: The `handout.cls` seems to be a little bit aged, no apparent updates

Comment: Try `\documentclass[solutions]{handout}`

Comment: I tried that, it created a blank document. I looked in the .cls class for how to link the solutions doc to the questions, found nothing.

Comment: @AnonE.Muss: Do you have a defined question/solution pair at all?

Comment: Yeah, I've got a few. I'll edit the question so it's got some of the code I wrote.

Comment: @Anon E.Muss:  You have `\documentclass[soln]{handout}` ... and it is not compilable. After correcting it and using `solution` instead of `soln` it works. The class file does not complain about the unknown `soln` option, unfortunately

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your patience with me. One more question, do you think I can create a solutions document separate from the questions document (or on another page, either works) without copying the code? In other words, can I print the solutions later in the document or in another document altogether? The `\showsoln` doesn't work here..

Comment: @AnonE.Muss: I have not studied the class file enough to give a clear answer. As far as I understand the class, I must give a disappointing answer: No. I think, you should use something like `exam` or `exsheets` rather

Answer (score 2):

The `handout` class does not have a `soln` option, the only declared option is  `solution`.

The macro `\showsoln` shows the 'solutions'.

In general, such packages (or classes)  as `exam`, `exsheets` etc. should be preferred for those purposes.

```
\documentclass[solution]{handout}

\SetInstructor{omitted instructor}
\SetCourseTitle{omitted course title}
\SetHandoutTitle{omitted handout title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{questions}
\item What is $1+1$?
  \soln{1.5in}{\framebox{$2$}.}

\item What is $2+2$?
  \soln{2in}{\framebox{$4$}.}
\end{questions}
\showsoln
\end{document}
```

[image]