# exam doc. class: making a grading key / grading guide?

Tags: exam

I'm using LaTeX and the exam document class to put together an exam.  I know that I can use the solution environments to create a copy of the exam that has the solutions included (in addition to the questions).

I'd like to create a separate document that has the solutions and bulleted lists of point deductions (without any questions, grading tables, etc).

I'm happy enough to include the list of point deductions in the questions' solutions but I don't want to reprint all the questions themselves.

Is there any way to produce a .PDF that includes only the solution blocks?

[This solution here on StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237849/131222) is about the closest that I've found so far.

Comment: Probably, the exam package https://ctan.org/pkg/exam provides what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's the document class that I'm using. I've been through most of the manual and haven't found anything about putting the solutions into a separate file

Answer (score 1):

After a decent night's sleep the answer came to me:

```
\ifprintanswers <------
% answers go here, using the solution I linked to above
\else <------
% exam itself, with questions, goes here
\begin{questions}
    \pointsinrightmargin
    %etc
\end{questions}
\fi <------
```

I appreciate y'alls patience with me as I figure out the basics. No, no, stay where you are - I'll show myself out, thanks :)