# Strange reference number for main figure label containing subfigures

Tags: subfloats, labels

I have problem in referencing number for main figure label. I have this code :

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering

\subfigure[11a's signal strength]{
    \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {fig/cdf_sig11a.eps}
    \label{cdf_sig11a}
}
\hspace{0.2cm}
\subfigure[11n's signal strength]{
    \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {fig/cdf_sig11n.eps}
    \label{cdf_sig11n}
}

\label{coverage_comparison}
\caption{Coverage comparison in various location}
\end{figure}
```

When I use Fig. \ref{coverage_comparison}, it shows Fig. II-C. It should be Fig. 4.

This only happens when I use subfigure and use main figure label but if I use Fig. \ref{cdf_sig11n}, it shows correct reference number Fig. 4(b).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Place the `label` *after* (or within) the `caption`.

Comment: thanks it works, I didn't know that the position of label would affect the result

Comment: See for example [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325) and [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280). And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".