# Reference to the name of subequations

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, subequations

I have a formulation that consists of several subequations that I would like to refer to as a formulation and as individual equation in my article. Right now I have this:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\begin{subequations}
MySubequation
\begin{align}
    a = b \label{eq:1a}\\
    a = c \label{eq:2b}\\
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

I would like to refer to this formulation in text as "MySubequation" and hyperlink it to the formulation. However, if I use `\ref{MySubequation}` it only shows the counter number for the formulation. Is there any way I can reference to a set of subequations as a name?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you turn your snippet into a complete minimum working example? It would really help community members to study your problem. Welcome :)

Comment: Use \hyperlink and \hypertarget.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options that you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\newcommand{\fourthoffive}[5]{#4}

\newcommand{\hyperlinktoeqn}[2]{%
  \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \hyperlink\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \fourthoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname}{#2}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{subequations}

\hyperlinktoeqn{eq:1a}{MySubequation1}
\hyperlink{myeqn}{MySubequation2}
\begin{align}
  a &= b \label{eq:1a}\raisebox{\HyperRaiseLinkDefault}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{myeqn}} \\
  a &= c \label{eq:2b}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

While both `MySubequation1` and `MySubequation2` point to the first sub-equation, they approach it differently.

1. The first extracts the regular hyperlink inserted by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as being a combination of elements. Specific to equations within `article`, the reference is comprised on 5 elements:

   1. the reference (`\@currentlabel` during `\label`-making)
   2. the page (`\thepage` at the time of page shipout)
   3. the title (used by [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) as `\@currentlabelname`)
   4. the hyperlink name (`\@currentHref`, as constructed by `hyperref`)
   5. blank - `{}`

   What we're interested in is extracting "4. the hyperlink name". For this we use `\fourthoffive` after extracting the appropriate reference details (each label `<label>` is stored in the `.aux` as `\r@<label>`; see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)). Some testing is performed in order to make sure the label exists, together with a whole lot of `\expandafter`s in order to ensure we retrieve the correct low-level components.
2. For the second `MySubequation2` link, we set a `\hypertarget` within the first sub-equation, raised (by `\HyperRaiseLinkDefault` or `\baselineskip`, the typical default) in order to land with the entire equation still visible.

   A straight-forward `\hyperlink{<link>}{<text>}` to the appropriate target suffices in this case.