# Referencing theorems by numbers

Tags: cross-referencing

I was wondering if there was a way that I could reference the numbers of the theorems in my document would actually having to write "theorem 1.11". So that if the numbering of my theorems change then my referencing of them automatically does as well?

Thanks for any help

Comment: @IanThompson that is about referencing sections and my question is about referencing theorems/lemmas. I thought there might be a way to do what is in that link automatically for theorems.

Comment: @IanThompson It would be good if you update your answer to cover also this case.

Comment: @egreg --- done.

Comment: @IanThompson I meant adding something that can cover also *this* problem. A newbie might not know that `\label` is allowed also after `\begin{thm}` and so on.

Comment: @egreg --- ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: also useful -- [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280) -- although that one doesn't mention theorems (or `cleveref`) either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cleveref-package](http://bay.uchicago.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) to solve your problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{Th_1}
This is my theorem
\end{theorem}

From \cref{Th_1} ...

\end{document}
```