# How do I refer Appendix in latex so as to display 'A' or 'B' in my paper

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I want to refer appendix in my paper.

Here is my sample latex code:

```
\section{hello1}
\label{h1}
bala.......

\section{hello2}
\label{h2}
bala.....

\appendix
\label{appendix}
\section{}
bala....
```

Here is what the appendix displays:

[image]

I use \ref to link sections and \eqref to refer equations, and \autoref to refer figs and tables. How do I refer appendix to display 'A'  in papers?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Use `\appendix\section{foo}\label{sec.foo}` and then call its label `\ref{sec.foo}`.

Comment: `\label` should be placed *after* the "counter-stepping mechanism" (the sectional unit in your case). See [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to leave the \section{} empty. But this time \ref{sec.foo} displays 'Appendix A'. But I only want it to display 'A'. How could I do it?

Comment: I suppose you are using specialized package for references?

Comment: Yes. I use hyperref package, but I only use it to ref table and fig by \autoref.

Answer (score 38):

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

Then in the body of the text.

```
This is a reference to the graph appendix \ref{appendix:graph}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Graph Appendix}
\label{appendix:graph}
This is the graph appendix...

\section{Another Appendix}

\end{appendices}
```

Result in body of text:

[image: reference to appendix latex]

Appendix:

[image: appendix for graph]

Comment: There is no *necessity* to load [`appendix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix).

Answer (score 22):

You don't necessarily need to import any packages. You can have appendices defined like the following:

```
\appendix

\section{Appendix: Rule Tables for Chapter 2}
\label{appendix:a}
```

And refer to them using:

```
\ref{appendix:a}
```