# How to reference an appendix by letter

Tags: sectioning, appendix

From the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270484/201720,

one can refer to an appendix by letter, which is what I want to achieve. However, I do not want the output to be:
[image]

Instead, I want the following:

- I want to add a section number before "Appendices"
- Instead of "A Graph Appendix", I want "Appendix A: Graph Appendix

***In other words, I want the output to be like this*** (in my case, appendices will be section 9):
[image]

Is there a way to do this?

I could write (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30123/201720):

```
\section{Appendices}
\subsection*{Appendix A: Graph Appendix} \label{appendix:a}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{}Appendix A: Graph Appendix}
This is the graph appendix. It is appendix \ref{appendix:a}.
```

Because I do not want the subsection to be numbered. But when I do this, latex references section 9 (because of the asterisk*, I think), so I get this:
[image]

But even if I remove the asterisk, latex will reference section 9.1. i.e. I will get this:
[image]

But again, that is not what I want. What I want is this:
[image]

Comment: I think if you use package appendix you can put \begin{appendices} and \end{appendices} and the chapters you put inbetween there will automatically get letters instead of numbers.

Comment: Yes, but if I do that, there won't be a number before "Appendices" (which I want). Plus, for the first appendix, it will say "A Graph Appendix", but I want it to say "Appendix A: Graph Appendix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `appendix` package with the option `[title]`. To get the numbered Appendices section you simply put it before the `\start{appendices}` call.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Two}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Appendices}
\begin{appendices}

\section{Alpha}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Beta}
\lipsum[4]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but this should be fine as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: I notice now that I did not include the colon that you had in your example. Sorry about that. You can achieve this with package titlesec and "\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{\appendixname{} \thesection:}{20pt}{\bfseries\Large}" just after \begin{appendices} (sorry again for omitting this).

Comment: No problem at all! Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!