# Аnalog of \ifodd condition for verification if page number is equal to some constant

Tags: conditionals

I have a great example of using `\ifodd` condition if `\makeatletter` environment showed by @Symbol 1.

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@oddhead
\newbox\LT@evenhead
\def\endoddhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@oddhead}
\def\endevenhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@evenhead}
\def\LT@head{\ifodd\c@page\LT@oddhead\else\LT@evenhead}
\makeatother
\begin{landscape}\small\begin{longtabu}to\linewidth{lll XX XXXXX}
    \caption*{ Long caption of a long table}\\\toprule1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\midrule\endfirsthead
    \caption*{ (Cont) Long caption of a long table }\\\toprule1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\midrule\endoddhead
    \toprule1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\midrule\endevenhead
```

I want to add one more statement to check if pagenumber is equal to some constant. For example:

`\def\LT@head{\ifeq\c@page={some constant}\{some stuff}\else\LT@head}`

But I can't find analoge for `\ifodd` command in `\makeatletter` environment.
Any ideas?

EDIT: add minimal working example
EDIT2: reduced MWE and added @-sign before someconstant. If I will uncomment line with `\ifnum` compiler won't make a pdf. The warning message is `! Missing number, treated as zero.`. I'm still confused.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside,hidelinks]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}



\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@oddhead
\newbox\LT@evenhead
\newbox\LT@endhead
\newcommand{\@someconstant}{2}
\newcommand{\Endd}{End}
\def\endoddhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@oddhead}
\def\endevenhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@evenhead}
\def\endendhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@endhead}
\def\LT@head{\ifodd\c@page\LT@oddhead\else\LT@evenhead}
%\def\LT@head{\ifnum\c@page=\@someconstant\relax\Endd\else\LT@head\fi}
\makeatother



\begin{landscape}
  \small
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{ lll XX  XXXXX}

\caption*{ Long caption of a long table}\\\toprule1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\midrule\endfirsthead
    \caption*{ (Cont) Long caption of a long table }\\\toprule1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\midrule\endoddhead
    \toprule1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\midrule\endevenhead
    End\\\endendhead


  \bottomrule
  \endfoot

  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot




1-й

 & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 85,1--104,0 93,7 (6) & 100,6 (1) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ &  & Самки & —
 & 92,1--105,8 97,6 (4) & 137,6 (1) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 43,6–82,0 53,3 (20) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 2,3--4,2 \linebreak2,8 (6) & 3,2 (1) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 2,2--3,6\linebreak 2,7 (4) & 7,9 (1) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,2--1,8\linebreak 0,4 (20) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
\\

2-й & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 72,0--114,0
93,6 (16) & 104,3--132,3
113,4 (4) & 121,5--178,2
139,3 (9) & 
158,9 (1) & 193,7--212,7
175,6 (3) & —
 \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 77,5--110,4
95,2 (7) & 110,4--131,3
117,6 (4) & 167,8 (1) & —
 & 182,9 (1) & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 45,1--86,9
51,9 (40) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 1,1--5,1 \linebreak 2,7 (16) & 3,7--5,5 \linebreak 4,3  (4) &
 5,1--15,0\linebreak  9,2 (9) 
 & 17,0 (1) & 21,0--30,0 26,3 (3) & —
 \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 1,5--4,7
\linebreak2,8 (7) & 4,0--6,1
\linebreak5,1 (4) & 15,0 (1) & —
 & 34,0 (1) & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,2--1,3
\linebreak0,4 (40) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 

\\

3-й & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 85,8--114,6
100,4 (7) & 113,7--131,2
118,3 (5) & 124,0--172,7
148,3 (2) & 144,6  (1)
 & —
 & 181,7--184,0
182,8 (2) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 84,7--115,7
98,0 (9) & 109,1--156,4
133,3 (3) & 106,9--167,1
140,0 (3) & 159,3 (1) & 222,6 (1) & 170,2 (1) \\ 
 &  & juv & 42,3--90,4
61,0 (26) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 2,1--5,2
\linebreak3,7 (7) & 4,5--10,0
\linebreak5,8 (5) & 7,6--19,0
\linebreak13,3 (2) & 11,0 (1) & —
 & 23,5--24,9
24,2 (2) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 2,0--5,9
\linebreak3,5 (9) & 4,9--14,0
\linebreak9,7 (3) & 4,5--21,0
\linebreak12,5 (3) & 15,0 (1) & 39,0 (1) & 18,0 (1) \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,3--2,6
\linebreak0,9 (26) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 

\\

4-й & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 77,6--112,0
92,7 (14) & 115,2--140,2
127,7 (2) & 135,2 (1) & 146,1--181,1
159,9 (3) & 157,9 (1) & 175,4--244,7
210,0 (2) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 88,0--113,7
99,1 (4) & 105,0--157,1
135,4 (6) & 123,0--174,3
141,3 (6) & 134,2--182,3
160,1 (3) & 181,6--187,0
183,4 (3) & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 43,9--81,0
52,0 (19) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 1,2--5,0
\linebreak2,7 (14) & 5,0--12,0
\linebreak8,5 (2) & 10,9 (1) & 12,0--23,0
\linebreak16,6 (3) & 13,4 (1) & 17,0 (1) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 2,0--6,0
\linebreak3,2 (4) & 4,3--17,0
\linebreak9,3 (6) & 7,0--26,0
\linebreak13,0 (6) & 7,0--19,8
\linebreak14,4 (3) & 20,0--36,0
\linebreak25,3 (3) & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,2--2,3
\linebreak0,5 (19) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
\\


5-й & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 71,7--108,2
\linebreak91,3 (32) & 87,3--140,0
\linebreak110,6 (39) & 105,6--149,4
\linebreak126,8 (7) & 130,4--160,9
\linebreak149,6 (5) & 166,2 (1) & —
 \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 80,2--105,4
\linebreak93,2 (30) & 93,6--152,9
\linebreak114,0 (48) & 123,0--147,1
\linebreak136,3 (12) & 144,2--147,0
\linebreak145,6 (2) & 140,7--179,6
\linebreak160,1 (2) & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 43,0--99,5
\linebreak73,1(47) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 1,0--4,7
\linebreak2,6 (32) & 1,7--13,0
\linebreak4,6 (39) & 3,6--15,0
\linebreak8,37(7) & 9,1--21,0
\linebreak14,9 (5) & 11,6 (1) & —
 \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 1,7--4,7
\linebreak2,9 (30) & 2,0--17,0
\linebreak5,5 (48) & 7,9--15,4
\linebreak10,9 (12) & 9,9--13,0
\linebreak11,4 (2) & 12,3--28,0
\linebreak20,1 (2) & —
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,2--4,2
\linebreak1,4 (47) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{—
} \\ 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\\


6-й & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 61,0--147,4
\linebreak98,2 (19) & 104,1--166,3
\linebreak120,4 (27) & 119,1--189,3
\linebreak147,0 (12) & 139,0--175,4
\linebreak157,2 (3) & 176,6--215,0
\linebreak195,8 (2) & 199,1--267,0
\linebreak246,4 (5) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 78,2--139,6
\linebreak99,1 (15) & 93,3--162,4
\linebreak122,3 (23) & 119,0--177,0
\linebreak145,6 (6) & 145,8--169,7
\linebreak158,9 (4) & 203,6 (1) & 212,9 (1) \\ 
 &  & juv & 44,0--96,3
\linebreak64,4 (35) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 1,3--13,0
\linebreak5,0 (15) & 2,7--14,0
\linebreak5,9 (27) & 6,5--24,0
\linebreak12,0 (12) & 9,0--9,8
\linebreak9,4 (2) & 18,0--38,0
\linebreak28,0  (2) & 19,6--73,0
\linebreak49,7 (5) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 1,6--11,0
\linebreak4,4 (12) & 1,8--13,0
\linebreak6,3 (23) & 5,6--16,0
\linebreak11,3 (5) & 10,7--18,0
\linebreak13,9 (4) & 34,0 (1) & 36,0 (1) \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,2--3,0
\linebreak1,3 (35) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 

\\

7-й & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 69,6--131,3,5
\linebreak93,4 (39) & 83,5--159,1
\linebreak116,4 (41) & 105,4--181,8
\linebreak138,8 (14) & 132,0--168,0
\linebreak153,7 (5) & 134,9--178,9
\linebreak156,9 (2) & 193,5 (1) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 64,9--133,0
\linebreak88,2 (31) & 83,3--169,1
\linebreak121,6 (39) & 95,2--168,4
\linebreak136,9 (20) & 136,0--183,8
\linebreak158,8 (5) & 163,1--202,0
\linebreak177,1 (3) & 200,0 (1) \\ 
 &  & juv & 39,1--93,1
\linebreak61,3 (150) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 1,0--9,0
\linebreak3,0 (39) & 1,8--17,0
\linebreak6,3 (41) & 4,1--34,0
\linebreak12,1 (14) & 8,4--21,7
\linebreak15,2 (5) & 9,1--22,0
\linebreak15,5 (2) & 39,0 (1) \\ 
 &  & Самки & — & 1,0--8,7
\linebreak2,3 (31) & 1,7--22,0
\linebreak7,6 (39) & 4,0--24,0
\linebreak11,3 (20) & 9,0--26,0
\linebreak17,6 (5) & 15,0--39,0
\linebreak23,5 (3) & 51,0 (1)
 \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,1--3,5
\linebreak0,8(150) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\
\\ 

Общее & Длина, мм & Самцы & —
 & 61,0--147,4
\linebreak93,6 (133) & 83,5--166,3
\linebreak115,5 (119) & 105,4--189,3
\linebreak140,4 (45) & 130,4--181,1
\linebreak153,9 (18) & 134,9--215,0
\linebreak178,9 (9) & 175,4--267,0
\linebreak221,1 (10) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 64,9--139,6
\linebreak93,5 (100) & 83,3--169,1
\linebreak119,7 (124) & 95,2--177,0
\linebreak139,1 (48) & 134,2--183,8
\linebreak157,4 (15) & 140,7--222,6
\linebreak182,8 (11) & 170,2--212,9
\linebreak194,4 (3) \\ 
 &  & juv & 39,1--99,5
\linebreak61,8 (337) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 
 & Масса, г & Самцы & —
 & 1,0--13,0
\linebreak3,1 (129) & 1,7--17,0
\linebreak5,8 (119) & 3,6 -34,0
\linebreak11,0  (45) & 8,4--23,0
\linebreak14,5 (17) & 9,1--38,0
\linebreak21,3 (9) & 17,0--73,0
\linebreak39,4 (9) \\ 
 &  & Самки & —
 & 1,0--11,0
\linebreak2,9  (97) & 1,7--22,0
\linebreak6,6  (124) & 4,0--26,0
\linebreak11,5 (47) & 7,0--26,0
\linebreak14,8 (15) & 12,3--39,0
\linebreak26,7 (11) & 18,5--51,0
\linebreak35,1 (3) \\ 
 &  & juv & 0,1--4,2
\linebreak0,9 (337) & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 & —
 \\ 

\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\ifnum\c@page\@someconstant\relax...\else...\fi` where `\@someconstant` is a constant (integer).

Comment: Thank you for anwer. And how can I define my constant? \def\someconstant{236}? or there is another way?

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach for a LaTeX document. Rather than using `\def`, for example, it would be safer to use `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`. In any case, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. A complete, small document people can compile is much more useful than a mere fragment of code.

Comment: I tried this: ``\newcommand{\someconstant}{4}``
``\newcommand{\Endd}{End}``  ``\def\LT@head{\ifnum\c@page\@someconstant\relax\Endd\else\LT@head\fi}`` But it fails. pdfLates said ``! Undefined control sequence.``

Comment: I think you need `\newcommand{\@someconstant}{4}`.

Comment: I change newcommand as you told. Compiler said that I miss ``=`` after ``\ifnum``. I added. Now compiler said ``! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].``

Comment: Could you please reduce your example to the minimum needed to reproduce the situation? Take out packages which are irrelevant at least. (You aren't including graphics. I can't see what requires `etoolbox`. Do you need all of the table packages for your sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is more general in terms of your question: How to check for the page number being something specific; not just odd?

Use [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount).

Why? When you're talking about page numbers you have to remember that TeX's page builder is asynchronous, and you could end up testing for a page number that you're actually not on. As such, using references is the best way to achieve the correct page number. And when you're wanting to compare reference counters, `refcount` does the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount,lipsum}
\begin{document}
Label \verb|abc| is on page~\pageref{abc}.
\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{abc}=5
  True
\else
  False
\fi

\lipsum[1-25]
\label{abc}
\lipsum[26-50]
\end{document}
```

After the first compilation, the reference is not yet available, and `\getpagerefnumber{<label>}` defaults to `0`. So for the correct output, you need [compile at least twice on the first go](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764), after which the references would just have to be settled in order for the condition to be evaluated properly. Regardless, LaTeX will warn of any reference issues, if they exist.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I definitely will use it, but in my particular situation it won't help. But, anyway, I recieve an answer.