# How to put a figure in one column and its caption in another column in a two column article latex

Tags: floats

Could some one help me to figure this issue out? I have a two column article and I have figures that are long. They fit in one column and that's ok but if I want to add the caption under the figure, the tex will be too large and does not fit in that column. Is there a way to put the figure in one column and the caption in front of it in the other column?!
I tried different things such as figure* or floatrow but that does not give me what I want.

Comment: The figure* should work, but figure (over two column) will be mowed to second page. Please provide MWE that we can see, what you don't liked, i.e. how you like to positioned the figure and caption.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can place the image and an accompanying caption in two separate floats, since nothing prevents you from doing that. That is, a `figure` is just a float and can contain virtually anything (or nothing); a `\caption` without an image, or an image without a `\caption`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.6\textheight]{example-image}
  %\caption{This is a caption belonging to the figure on right right.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[t]
  %\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.6\textheight]{example-image}
  \caption{This is a caption belonging to the figure on the left.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you ensure that the two floats are positioned on the same page, and that the caption does not appear on the next page instead?

Comment: @Banana: Manual float placement like this is often prone to repetitive trial and error.  So, place the two until they work for you. If you insert content prior to the placement, you may have to go back and change the placement (within the code) so they result in something you're after. It would be possible to automate this process, but it's easier to just move the float placement within the code until the desires output is achieved. Of course, the limiting factor here is the 2-column layout. Without it, things would be far easier.

Comment: This breaks the label. How can it be fixed?

Comment: @Patrick: Define what you mean by "break."

Comment: Sorry, @Werner. I meant that just adding `\label{...}` to the second `\begin{figure}`, the one with the `\caption{...}`, does not work. It does not find the label when compiling the document.

Comment: @Patrick: Did you put [`\label` *after* `\caption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)?