# Figure caption continuing on next column

Tags: floats, captions

In a two-column document, I have a figure that span almost the whole column, leaving not enough room for the caption in the remaining part of the column. Therefore, I want the caption to continue in the next column. I've tried several approaches including \captionof and \contcaption (package ccaption) and haven't been able to achieve the desired result. I've been able to move the whole caption to the next column, but the editorial staff of the journal I'm submitting to (The Cryosphere) have rejected that solution.
I've edited a capture of my document in photoshop to illustrate the desired result:
[image]

I would like to provide a generic minimal working example, but I'm tied to the journal-provided document class. The files associated to the document class together with the MWE can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qsydw1dpji4kvv/Minimal%20working%20example.zip?dl=0). The content of the MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[journal abbreviation]{copernicus}

%% \usepackage commands included in the copernicus.cls:
%\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{rotating} 

\usepackage{blindtext}%Only used in this minimal example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, height=0.9\textheight]{example-image}
\caption{\blindtext[2]}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

if the image were smaller (for example 0.6\textheight) it looks like this:
[image]

However for a long image (0.9\textheight) it looks like this
[image]

And I need the figure to stay in the left column and the caption to continue in the right column as shown in the first image.

Any clues on how to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Have you seen [How to put a figure in one column and its caption in another column in a two column article latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204610/124842)? Does it help? Otherwise it is always a good idea to add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) to the question, that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier with compilable code.

Comment: One can use \vsplit to separate a caption into two parts, provided you know how much space is left in the first column.  You will have to insert the \vsplit inside \@makecaption (which is package dependent) and save the second half globally.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for the comment. I tried that, but the editorial staff of the journal rejected that option. They want the legend starting at the bottom of the figure. I've added a MWE and some screenshots of the outputs. I hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm afraid I will need a more detailed explanation than that, sorry. I don't know how to add something inside \@makecaption. I've tried adding \vsplit inside \caption and I get errors. I've added a MWE and some screenshots, I hope that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that copernicus.cls defines its own `\@makecaption`.

This solution adds two commands: `\splitcaption` and `\mergecaption`.  `\splitcaotion` adds an argument for the available space remaining (which you must compute),  `\mergecaption` creates a new figure to handle the remainder of the caption (if any).  It should be used immediately after the original figure environment (NOT inside).

One can use `\afterpage` to force the figure into the left column.  Note: `\afterpage` does not work with `\blindtext`, probably as it forms one huge paragraph.

```
\documentclass[journal abbreviation]{copernicus}

%% \usepackage commands included in the copernicus.cls:
%\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{rotating} 

\usepackage{blindtext}%Only used in this minimal example
\usepackage{lipsum}%forms paragraphs
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newsavebox{\splitcaptionbox}
\newlength{\splitcaptionheight}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makesplitcaption#1#2{% see \@makecaption from copernicux.cls (figure only)
  \if@stage@final
    \vskip0.7\abovecaptionskip
    \addtolength{\splitcaptionheight}{-0.7\abovecaptionskip}%
  \else
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip\goodbreak
    \addtolength{\splitcaptionheight}{-\abovecaptionskip}%
  \fi
  \setbox\splitcaptionbox=\vbox{\interlinepenalty 0
    \reset@font\small{\bfseries#1.} #2\par}%
  \vsplit\splitcaptionbox to \splitcaptionheight
  \global\setbox\splitcaptionbox=\box\splitcaptionbox
  \if@cop@home\ifonline\ifnum\csname c@\@captype\endcsname=1 % for 1st fig or tab only
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@num\@captype{}}%
    \hypertarget{\@captype}{}%
  \fi\fi\fi}

\newcommand{\splitcaption}[3][\empty]% #1=short caption (optional), #2=caption, #3=remaining height
 {\setlength{\splitcaptionheight}{#3}%
  \let\cop@makecaption=\@makecaption
  \let\@makecaption=\@makesplitcaption
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \caption{#2}%
  \else
    \caption[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
  \let\@makecaption=\cop@makecaption}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mergecaption}{\ifdim\ht\splitcaptionbox>0pt
  \begin{figure}[tp]
  \box\splitcaptionbox
  \end{figure}
\fi}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth, height=0.9\textheight]{example-image}
\splitcaption{\blindtext}{0.1\textheight}
\end{figure}%
\mergecaption}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the time you took to answer. I would just add that the \label tag must go inside \splitcaption, otherwise it is not properly recognized. It took me a while to figure that out.
Thanks again!

Comment: That's due to the \bgroup ... \egroup.  I might be able to fix that.

Comment: It seems it's not working in a \documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex62} for some reason. The text always starts from its middle and after compile there is an "Undefined control sequence" error message complaining about \makecaption. Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: Assuming you meant \@makecaption, aastex62 must be using a totally custom caption system.  Generally, one shouldn't mess with the publications, style wise.