# How to create custom labels which can be referenced?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I would like to label the hypotheses in my thesis similar to equations (e.g., the first hypothesis in chapter 3 should be “H-3.1”). Also similar to equations, I would like to reference these hypotheses.
What I got so far is the following (which is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7797554/3162788)):

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{hypCNT}
\newcommand{\hypCnt}[2]{\refstepcounter{hypCNT}\label{#1}H-\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{hypCNT}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}

Hypotheses: \\
Pigs can fly (\hypCnt{hyp:H1}) \\
The world is a disk (\hypCnt{hyp:H2})\\

Hypotheses \ref{hyp:H1} on page \pageref{hyp:H1}
    \end{document}
```

Which leads to:

> **Chapter 1** 
>  
>   **Lorem** 
>  
>   Hypotheses: 
>  
>   Pigs can ﬂy (H-1.1 
>  
>   The world is a disk (H-1.2 
>  
>  
>   Hypotheses 1 on page 1

This solution is close but not exactly what I would like to have. Actually I would like the `H-\arabic{chapter}` to be part of the label. Of course I could define another `\newcommand{\refHyp}` also containing the `H-\arabic{chapter}` part. However, if I would reference a H-label out of another chapter I would get the chapter number of the current chapter and not the one I am actually referencing to.

Another strange thing: Why does the closing bracket disappear behind the `\hypCnt{}`?

Any ideas appreciated a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Have you looked at `fancyref` or `cleverref`?

Comment: The `)` is swallowed and digested by the fact that `\hypcnt` has two arguments but you call it with just one!

Comment: ...the closing bracket disappears because you've defined `\hypCnt` to take 2 arguments yet you only supply one (explicitly). As such, TeX grabs whatever token follows your use of `\hypCnt{.}`, which is `)` in this case.

Comment: Ah, thx @ChristianHupfer and @Werner: That sounds reasonable. Strange thing: I would swear 30 min ago Latex did not compile when defining `\hypCnt` with one argument only. Now, one argument is perfectly fine.
@cfr: Thanks for the hint. I am going to check these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the use of you hypothesis construction, the following is a better suit for what you're after:

```
\newcounter{hypCNT}[chapter]% Hypothesis counter
% Representation of hypothesis counter: H-<chap>.<hypCNT>
\renewcommand{\thehypCNT}{H-\thechapter.\arabic{hypCNT}}
\newcommand{\hypCnt}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{hypCNT}% Step hypothesis counter
  \thehypCNT% Print hypothesis counter
  \label{#1}}% Mark with label
```

Note the use of `\thechapter` rather than `\arabic{chapter}`. This is to let the reference be dependent on whatever type of representation is used for the `chapter` counter, rather than explicitly stating it will be `\arabic`. Such recursive/dependent usages is common when dealing with sub-counters.

Consider reading up on [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764) where it is discussed what happens with a call to `\label{..}`. What is stored for future reference is `\@currentlabel`, which is set based on the last `\refstepcounter`'s representation - `\the<cnt>`. Hence the fact that I've updated the way the counter looks via `\thehypCNT`.

Comment: You may wish to have the `hypCNT` counter reset with every chapter (not sure). For that, use `\newcounter{hypCNT}[chapter]`...