# Reference Equation (\eqref) Before Equation Is Written/Defined

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I'm trying to do the following: I'd like to say "as shown in $(18)$ below", where $(18)$ is a certain equation that (which I shall label `norm-split`), as per the 'below', I have not yet written. Is there a way (or, rather, what is the way) that I can do this with `\eqref`? At the moment, if I just replace "$(18)$" with "`\eqref{norm-split}`", then it just puts $(5.2)$, which is the (sub)section number.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

I'm using TeXstudio under MiKTeX. Also, this is the first day that I've been using TeX - I have always previously used MathJax - so I'm a bit of a noob at it in some ways, but in others I know a reasonable amount!

---

Here's my code (with the intermediary bits taken out):

```
as shown in \eqref{norm-split} below. We keep the $u \ge 0$ constraint
in the primal objective, however. This is because we can still do
backwards primal step explicitly and ... we may write
\label{norm-split}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\| (v,w) - (v',w') \| &= \|v-v'\|_q^q + \|w-w'\|_2^2 \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \|v^i - v'^i\|_q^q + \|w - w'\|_2^2,
\end{split}
\end{align}
the backwards dual step ...
```

Comment: You need an equation with a label to reference it. If the equation isn't written yet (hence not labeled) I would suggest to use a package like `todonotes`, which will let you write reminders in the margin, at the places where you want to insert cross-references.

Comment: `\eqref{norm-split}` should never produce the section number  but it is hard to debug code you have not shown. Either it should give the equation number (if `\label{norm-split}` is in the equation) or it should give an undefined label warning and print ?? (if the equation is not yet in the document).

Comment: Ah, let me clarify: by "not yet written", I mean that the equation is below. I have typed it in, just "yet" is referring to ordering in the document.

Comment: Then you have something wrong, most likely `\label` is not in the equation, but as I say it is hard if you do not give any clues as to what the input looks like.

Comment: Ok, yeah, "\label" is outside the "\begin{align} ... \end{align}" because I wanted the label centralised between the two lines - is this not necessary?

Comment: No. `\label` doesn't print anything. It is just used to store the value of the currently active counter. This is **not** the equation counter if `\label` was placed outside an equation environment.

Comment: You have `\label` out of the math environment, there's nothing to refer but the section command. You need to put it *inside*. In any case, what's the point of using `{align}` and `{split}`? Either use `{align}` or `{equation}` with `{split}`.

Comment: @AlexG - yeah, I realise label doesn't print anything... and thinking about it now that means that there's no way it could change what I wanted! Oops!

Comment: @Manuel As I said, this is the first day I've used LaTeX, and I looked online to see how to only put the one equation number on, and I just copied the way an answer on here had done it... although they were actually aligning something...

Comment: Look into the amsmath documentation for examples (`texdoc amsldoc`). Equations (single ones, aligned ones, multiline ones etc.) are automatically numbered. The cited doc is full of examples that make sense.

Comment: @AlexG You could make an answer.

Comment: Ok, it is working now. I changed "align" to "equation" and moved the "label" to be after "equation" and before "split".

Comment: \label grabs the last counter to call \refstepcounter (possibly the page number). Putting it right after \begin{align} is safest.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. I have it working now. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has been resolved within the comments as a basic misunderstanding regarding the use of the `\label`-`\ref` system. As generic reference, consider reading up on [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

Comment: That's fine by me :) -- close away!