# How to define a new lable type such as fig and tab for a new float?

Tags: labels

I have define a new float "scheme" and want to reference it as figure or table floats do. How could I define a new label type for the "scheme" float to reference it in the article? I have tried to use fig or tab labels, but they do not work. See the picture. [image]

Tex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}           % Use table caption
\usepackage{chemfig}           % Use chemical strutures
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=ext, name=Scheme, placement=tbph!]{scheme}
\captionsetup[scheme]{labelsep=period, font={small, bf}, skip=8pt}

\begin{document}
This is a chemical reaction:

\begin{scheme}[h!]
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{scheme}
\centering
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} \+ \chemfig{H_2} \arrow \chemfig{*6(-(-H)=-=(-H)-=)}
\schemestop
\label{sh1}  % define a new label type for scheme float
\caption{Reaction of Benzene Synthesis}
\end{scheme}

A relatively simple, as shown in Scheme~\ref{sh1}, is neutralized by the solution contained within it to form a charged double layer, which under the influence of an applied electric field leads to the electroosmotic mobilization of the solution.

\end{document}
```

Comment: as always, you need to run latex twice for the cross references to be resolved

Comment: See [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `\label` *after* `\caption`. The `\caption` macro is the one actually stepping the associated counter which is referred to by `\label` and `\ref`. This is the same for `figure`, `table` or any newly defined float:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}           % Use table caption
\usepackage{chemfig}           % Use chemical strutures
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=ext, name=Scheme, placement=tbph!]{scheme}
\captionsetup[scheme]{labelsep=period, font={small, bf}, skip=8pt}

\begin{document}
This is a chemical reaction:

\begin{scheme}
% \renewcommand*{\figurename}{scheme}
  \centering
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} \+ \chemfig{H_2} \arrow \chemfig{*6(-(-H)=-=(-H)-=)}
  \schemestop
  \caption{Reaction of Benzene Synthesis}
  \label{sh1}  % define a new label type for scheme float
\end{scheme}

A relatively simple, as shown in Scheme~\ref{sh1}, is neutralized by the
solution contained within it to form a charged double layer, which under the
influence of an applied electric field leads to the electroosmotic
mobilization of the solution.

\end{document}
```

[image]