# What should be the relative positioning between label and caption in a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

When writing I normally don't care if I write first the caption or the label of a figure. A friend recently told me to write always the caption first and then the label.

What reasons are to do this? Are there any advantages by writing it this way?

Comment: The label have to be after (or within) the caption, otherwise cross references doesn't work. See e.g. [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325) Edit: See also [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)

Comment: it doesn't work at all if you put the label first, actually best is to put the label inside the caption argument.

Answer (score 4):

Your friend is right. The `\label` command will store the latest updated counter, which for the figure is done by `\caption`. In the code below try to move the \label to before the `\caption` and compile twice. Then it refers to the latest updated counter, in this case the section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Test section one}
Bla bla 
\section{Test section two}
Bla bla 
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \tikz\draw(0,0)rectangle(5,3);
  % \label{fig:one}
  \caption{Test}
  \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}
Bla in Fig~\ref{fig:one}.
\end{document}
```