# How to make linkable tags

Tags: cross-referencing

I am new to tex.SE!

I know how to use the most basic LaTeX features, like compiling a pdf document from a single source file. But I feel I can only use 1% of the full potential of LaTeX.

One thing that bothers me most is that I can't use \tag feature. For example, `\label {eq:firstexp}` and then `(\ref {eq:firstexp})` gives me (?) instead of (1.1). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run LaTeX twice?

Comment: @JosephWright How twice? I use TeXworks on Ubuntu 14.04 to compile my .tex files. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Typeset the document twice: in TeXworks, press the green button or use Ctrl-T, let it run, then do it again.

Comment: @JosephWright Let me try.

Comment: @JosephWright Oh my God! It worked! Thank you, thank you, thank you! Should I do that every time I compile, like double-compiling?

Comment: Double-compiling is necessary if cross-references, bibliographic items, or items for the table of contents have changed; otherwise, a single recompilation is fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not realize that the document needed to be compiled twice before `\ref`' appear.

Comment: @Andrew That's why I asked.

Comment: @NimaBavari Closing the question is just a way of recording that your question has been answered even though there is no "answer" given in the answer boxes below.

Comment: @NimaBavari: You have to compile twice at the first go, or whenever reference may have changed. Once the references have settled, a single compilation should suffice. See [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).