# Manipulating \nameref title

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, expansion, strings, xstring

I'm trying to create a new command that will act like `\nameref` but the output will manipulate the original name of what I'm referencing.
To be more specific, I'll give an example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getnamereftext}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\shortRef}[1]{%
  \StrBefore{\getnamereftext{#1}}{:}[\myref]%
  \IfBeginWith{\myref}{``}{\StrBetween{\myref}{``}{''}}{\myref}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{``First Part'': Second Part}
\label{ch:1}

\section{This section doesn't have parts}
\label{sc:1}
\section{section parts: it contains them}
\label{sc:2}

I want to be able to reference Section~``\shortRef{sc:2}'' and only show the first part.
But I also want it to be a link so it's clickable and pointing to the actual chapter/section.
I want \nameref{sc:2} to still display the full name.

And I want to remove any quotations from the first part if they are present.
So citing Chapter~``\shortRef{ch:1}'' wouldn't show double quotation marks.

\end{document}
```

I got the `\getnamereftext` command from [How to use \nameref with xstring package to check string length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296643/how-to-use-nameref-with-xstring-package-to-check-string-length/296645#296645)

I don't want to redefine `\nameref` because I still want to be able to cite the chapter with its full name as shown in the example. I also don't want to use `\chapter[short name]{long name}` because that will also make all `\nameref` use the short name and, worst of all, my table of contents will also use the short name (this is very important, hence adding `\tableofcontents` command to the example).

The code is also trying to remove quotation marks if present.

The missing part of the code is creating a link from the reference. I have no idea how to do this. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be fixed by adding `%` characters at the end of several lines (see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/73317)). Then you can use the `\hyperref` command from package `hyperref` to create the desired link:

> `\hyperref[LaTeX label]{text}`

Also:

- don't forget the `\makeatother`;
- make sure you load `hyperref` last (except if you also load `cleveref`, which has to be loaded *after* `hyperref`).

This gives:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}           % load this last, except cleveref comes after

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\getnamereftext}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\shortRef}[1]{%
  \StrBefore{\getnamereftext{#1}}{:}[\myref]%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{\IfBeginWith{\myref}{``}{\StrBetween{\myref}{``}{''}}{\myref}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{``First Part'': Second Part}
\label{ch:1}

\section{This section doesn't have parts}
\label{sc:1}
\section{section parts: it contains them}
\label{sc:2}

I want to be able to reference Section~``\shortRef{sc:2}'' and only show the
first part. But I also want it to be a link so it's clickable and pointing to
the actual chapter/section. I want \nameref{sc:2} to still display the full
name.

And I want to remove any quotations from the first part if they are present.
So citing Chapter~``\shortRef{ch:1}'' wouldn't show double quotation marks.

\end{document}
```

[image]

(...)

[image]

This should work as you want. However, my personal preference would be to implement this differently, as we'll see.

## Alternate implementation

I'd suggest to implement this using the `refcount` package in order to extract the `nameref` of your sectioning commands. It is a very convenient package that allows one to retrieve everything from references (`\ref` text, page number, `nameref` and more) in an expandable manner. Moreover, it doesn't make you depend on a particular syntax for the `\r@〈ref〉` macro used in your `\getnamereftext` command (this syntax can depend on the particular packages loaded by your document, such as `nameref`, `hyperref` and `cleveref`). In short, `refcount` handles all the boring details for you.

I also propose to use `l3regex` instead of `xstring`. `l3regex` is part of the `expl3` language and is a very powerful tool for “string processing” (in the LaTeX world, this would translate into *token list* processing). Here we go:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}           % load this last, except cleveref comes after

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__felipe_name_tl

% Code-level command
\cs_new_protected:Npn \felipe_short_ref:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__felipe_name_tl { \getrefbykeydefault {#1} { name } { ?? } }
    % Print the “Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references
    % right.” message if appropriate.
    \refused {#1}
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A ( [^\cO\:]* ) ( \cO\: .* )? \Z } { \1 }
      \l__felipe_name_tl
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A \`\` (.*) \'\' \Z } { \1 } \l__felipe_name_tl
    \hyperref [{#1}] { \l__felipe_name_tl }
  }

% Document-level command
\NewDocumentCommand \shortRef { m }
  { \felipe_short_ref:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{``First Part'': Second Part}
\label{ch:1}

\section{This section doesn't have parts}
\label{sc:1}
\section{Section parts: it contains them}
\label{sc:2}

I want to be able to reference Section~``\shortRef{sc:2}'' and only show the
first part. But I also want it to be a link so it's clickable and pointing to
the actual chapter/section. I want \nameref{sc:2} to still display the full
name.

And I want to remove any quotations from the first part if they are present.
So citing Chapter~``\shortRef{ch:1}'' wouldn't show double quotation marks.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not only because you solved my problem but using the `refcount` package makes things so much easier and my code is easier to understand! I'm not familiar with `l3regex` or `expl3` so your alternative code doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that I don't need `makeatletter` and `makeatother` when using `refcount` since there's no `@` character used anywhere. Is this true?

Comment: Glad to hear this helped. You're correct regarding the `@` character. The reason why I tend to avoid `xstring` is that it [sometimes expands things in ways that are  not described in the documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527856/73317) (and alas, fixing that would certainly break existing code...). Don't forget to upvote the other answer, egreg helped you too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\hyperref[<label>]{<modified nameref>}`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getnamereftext}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\shortRef}[1]{%
  % get only what comes earlier than the colon
  \StrBefore{\getnamereftext{#1}}{:}[\myref]%
  % but if it starts with ``, we want only what's up to ''
  \IfBeginWith{\myref}{``}{\StrBetween{\myref}{``}{''}[\myref]}{}%
  \hyperref[#1]{\myref}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{``First Part'': Second Part}
\label{ch:1}

\section{This section doesn't have parts}
\label{sc:1}
\section{section parts: it contains them}
\label{sc:2}

I want to be able to reference Section~``\shortRef{sc:2}'' and only show the first part.
But I also want it to be a link so it's clickable and pointing to the actual chapter/section.
I want \nameref{sc:2} to still display the full name.

And I want to remove any quotations from the first part if they are present.
So citing Chapter~``\shortRef{ch:1}'' wouldn't show double quotation marks.

\end{document}
```

[image]