# Figure reference problem

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I am using LaTeX with the help of TeXnicCenter. I try to add figure reference in my text but it did not work out.  Here is what I am doing.

Code:

```
Figure~\ref{fig:abc} shows the execution ............

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \includegraphics[height=8cm]{Path/abc.png}
  \caption{abc}
  \label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
```

then it shows as

> Figure ?? shows the execution of...

Comment: You have to compile a second time to solve the references.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/15925

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP problem is solved by comments.