# Weird output at top of document possibly related to includegraphics command with graphicx package

Tags: graphics, floats

I keep getting this Text right underneath the heading of my document, just 
"cosxx12."

When I delete the following lines

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=100mm]{expxcosx.png}
  \caption{$e^x$ vs. $\cos x$}
  \label{fig:Graph e^x vs. \cos x}
\end{figure}
```

The text disappears. I have no idea what is going on. What can I do to remove this?

Comment: How about not using `\cos` in your `\label`, but instead just `cos`. Also, don't use spaces...

Comment: hm I will try and do that....no spaces in the label? Now I am getting an invalid root error and nothing is compiling at all, is that possibly related?

Comment: Yes, delete your `.aux` and retry to compile.

Comment: @Werner oops got it that did it. So I guess there isn't a good way to format math within the label?

Comment: Why would you want to? A label is a document-internal identifier of something, that can later be referenced. Give it a good name, not an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use *strange things* in your `\label`s. In this case, math content. Here's what happens using a relevant example (following along with [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{$e^x \cos x$}
  \label{fig:e^x \cos x}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

After the first compilation, one would think there's something like `\newlabel{fig:e^x \cos x}{{<fig>}{<page>}}` in the `.aux`. However, this is not the case:

```
\newlabel{fig:e^x \mathop {\mathgroup \symoperators cos}\nolimits x}{{1}{1}}
```

`\cos` is fully-expanded, causing all sorts of problems. As such, avoid math-related content in your labels as a general rule, since they may be shorthand for <s>bigger</s> hidden things.

In fact, `\cos` even expands in the `\caption` (which may be used in `\listoffigures`) and therefore might be problematic. In this case its not, but it may help using `\protect\cos` in *moving arguments* like `\caption`.