# Refer to a paralist item in a section

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, paralist

I am using `paralist`'s `asparaenum` instead of subsections. Occasionally, though, I would like to refer to an `asparaenum` item. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{paralist}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The First}\label{1-0}
\section{One}\label{1-1}
\begin{asparaenum}
\item%1
Some stuff
\item%2
Important Stuff
\end{asparaenum}
Occasionally, I would like to refer to just the item Important Stuff in \Cref{1-1} \nameref{1-1} rather than to the whole section 1.
\end{document}
```

Comment: try to add labels after items, something like `\item\label{1-1-2}%2
Important Stuff` and then referencing it  for example `\ref{1-1-2}`. Is this what you like to achieve?

Comment: You get the manual of paralist with `texdoc paralist`, and then see page 6 for exactly the example, how to label an item. Besides that, having enumerations as subsections is a bad idea.

Comment: @Zarko I was so utterly convinced it couldn't be done that I did not even think of trying it. Thanks

Comment: @KeksDose I keep forgetting that there are a lot of answers in the manuals. Thanks. Besides that, I agree with you that having enumerations as subsections is a bad idea but I have always found subsections truly UGLY.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by comments.

Comment: @Zarko Alternatively, you could turn your comment into an answer which I would accept.

Comment: @schremmer, now is to late :) question is already closed :(

Comment: @Zarko Don't see what this has accomplished. But, for this mere user to avoid a repeat, how did the question "_not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX_. Yes, it was a "stupid" question which I should have been able to answer myself, but the "answers" let me do what I had failed to do on my own even though I have been writing mathematics in LaTeX for some fifteen years.

Comment: @schremmer, your question is not stupid. If you like to have an answer, I will reopen your question (but I'm not sure if will succeed) and wrote answer.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111280/understanding-how-references-and-labels-work

Comment: @Schweinebacke: yes, generally it is related, but this link doesn't deal wit referencing items in numerated list. I'm pretty  sure, that similar question was asked before, but now I haven't time for search for duplicate.

Comment: @KeksDose I have finally seen the wisdom of your "_having enumerations as subsections is a bad idea_". I had done it only because I had not been able to reformat `\subsection{}` which I am only now learning how to do. As a result I must apologize to the authors of both answers which I do not know how to both accept. Nevertheless, I learned a lot from them.

Comment: @Zarko Please see my comment to KeksDose.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Please see my comment to KeksDose.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add labels after items, something like `\item\label{1-1-2}%2 Important Stuff` and then referencing it for example `\ref{1-1-2}`

Excerpt from \verb+paralist+ package, page 6:

[image]

In your example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{paralist}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The First}\label{1-0}

Excerpt from \verb+paralist+ package, page 6:

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
As an example, we use \verb+asparaenum+ within this paragraph.
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   Every \verb+\item+ is basically set as a separate paragraph. The second
line is not indented (this is a feature, not a bug).
\item   The next \verb+\item+ looks like this and is labeled.
    \end{enumerate}
The example was produced by the following piece of code:
\begin{asparaenum}
\item Every \dots
\item The next \dots \label{pl1}
\end{asparaenum}
By saying \verb+\ref{pl1}+ we get \ref{pl1}.

The \verb+inparaenum+ environment formats an enumerated list within a paragraph, just like the one in the introduction.

The example in the introduction was set by the following commands:
\begin{verbatim}
\dots of an enumerated environment that
    \begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
    \item can be used within paragraphs,
    \item takes care of enumeration and
    \item has items that can be referenced. \label{pl2}
    \end{inparaenum}
Another posting mentioned ...
\end{verbatim}
By saying \verb+\ref{pl2}+ we get c.

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\section{One}\label{1-1}
In your case:
    \begin{asparaenum}
\item   Some stuff
\item\label{item:1-1-2} Important Stuff
    \end{asparaenum}
Occasionally, I would like to refer to just the item \emph{Important Stuff}, e.g \cref{item:1-1-2} in above list \dots

\section{Two}\label{1-2}
With use referencing some list item, you should be aware that when you do again like in the following case:
    \begin{asparaenum}
\item   Some stuff second time
\item\label{item:1-2-2} Important Stuff again
    \end{asparaenum}
the  \emph{Important Stuff again} has the same \verb+\cref+ mark as before, but corect hyperlink, e.g \cref{item:1-2-2},

\lipsum[2]


\newpage\noindent
which work correctly  from any part of document, e.g see \cref{item:1-2-2} on the page \pageref{item:1-2-2}!

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @schremmer, I succeed with suggestion for reopening of your question. Now I add my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Type the following in the preamble:

```
\crefname{aspar}{Important Item}{Important Items}
\Crefname{aspar}{Important Item}{Important Items}
\crefformat{aspar}{Important Item #1}
\newcommand{\labelasp}[1]{\label[aspar]{#1}} % a new command for custom referncing important items
```

Where `aspar` is a new label type for `cleveref` package to identify. `\labelasp` is a new command you can use to identify important items. Note that `Important Item` can be changed to whatever name you like to be introduced, but make sure that you set plural and singular properly.

A complete code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\crefname{aspar}{Important Item}{Important Items}
\Crefname{aspar}{Important Item}{Important Items}
\crefformat{aspar}{Important Item #1}
\newcommand{\labelasp}[1]{\label[aspar]{#1}} % a new command for custom referncing important items


\begin{document}

\chapter{The First}\label{1-0}
\section{One}\label{1-1}


\begin{asparaenum}
\item Some stuff
\item \labelasp{imp1}
Important stuff 2
\item \labelasp{imp2}
Important stuff 3
\item \labelasp{imp3}
Important stuff 4


\end{asparaenum}


Now you can refer to \cref{imp1} in page \labelcpageref{imp1} or multiple \cref{imp2,,imp3,,imp1} in \cref{1-1}. 


\end{document}
```