# Why does \ref not work with chngcntr?

Tags: cross-referencing, chngcntr

I want my figures to be captioned `Figure x.n` for the nth figure in chapter x. The below MWE gives correct figure numbers in the captions, but `\ref` gives the chapter numbers instead of `x.y`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}

\newcommand{\myfig}[3]
{
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \label{#1}
        \centering
        %\input{figures/#2}
        \caption{#3}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

\myfig{figone}{foo}{This is the first figure.}
\myfig{figtwo}{foo}{This is the second figure.}

\chapter{Chapter Two}

\myfig{figthree}{foo}{This is the third figure.}

\chapter{Chapter Three}

See figures \ref{figtwo} and \ref{figone} and \ref{figthree}.

\end{document}
```

I expected Chapter Three to contain

> See figures 1.2 and 1.1 and 2.1.

Instead it contains

> See figures 1 and 1 and 2.

How do I reference figures to get `x.n` numbering?

Comment: `\label` *must* come after `\caption`. The issue is *not* related to the use of the `chngcntr` package.

Comment: See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/2693).  Essentially a duplicate.

Comment: You're referencing the section counter because that's the last counter being used in `\refstepcounter` and `\label` grabs this information in order to provide the reference value