# \ref not printing anything after redefining \section

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am having trouble with `\ref` after redefining `\section`. I am working with a template given to me and previously they were changing the definition of `\thesection` to make the section headings appear as required. This in turn messed up equation numbering because I need "section.equation" and "section.subsection.equation" equation numbering (so the `\thesection` definition was coming through here). Instead, I returned `\thesection` to default defined in `article.cls` and set up the following for `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection`.

```
\def\section{\@ifstar\@mysection\@@mysection}
\def\subsection{\@ifstar\@mysubsection\@@mysubsection}
\def\subsubsection{\@ifstar\@mysubsubsection\@@mysubsubsection}
\newcommand{\@@mysection}[1]{%
    \vskip 24pt%
    \hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    \stepcounter{section}%
    \if@app%
        \bgroup%
        \Large\bfseries\Alph{section}. #1 \newline
        \egroup
        \numberwithin{equation}{section}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}
    \else%
        \def\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}%
        \bgroup%
        \Large\bfseries\@arabic\c@section. #1 \newline
        \egroup
        \numberwithin{equation}{section}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\@mysection}[1]{%
    \vskip 24pt%
    \hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    \bgroup%
    \Large\bfseries #1 \newline
    \egroup
}
\newcommand{\@@mysubsection}[1]{%
    \vskip 18pt%
    \hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    \stepcounter{subsection}%
    \if@app%
        \bgroup%
        \large\bfseries\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}. #1 \newline
        \egroup
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
        \renewcommand{\theequation{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{equation}}
    \else %
        \bgroup%
        \large\bfseries\@arabic\c@section.\@arabic\c@subsection. #1 \newline
        \egroup
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{equation}}
    \fi 
}
\newcommand{\@mysubsection}[1]{%
    \vskip 24pt%
    \hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    \bgroup%
    \large\bfseries #1 \newline
    \egroup
}
\newcommand{\@@mysubsubsection}[1]{%
    \vskip 18pt%
    \hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    \stepcounter{subsubsection}%
    \if@app%
        \bgroup%
        \normalsize\bfseries\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}. #1 \newline
        \egroup
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        \numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{equation}}
    \else %
        \bgroup%
        \normalsize\bfseries\@arabic\c@section.\@arabic\c@subsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection. #1 \newline
        \egroup
        \setcounter{equation}{0}
        \numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}
        \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{equation}}
    \fi 
}
\newcommand{\@mysubsubsection}[1]{%
    \vskip 24pt%
    \hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    \bgroup%
    \normalsize\bfseries #1 \newline
    \egroup
}
```

The trouble is that whenever I reference a section, subsection, or subsubsection with `\ref`, nothing is printed. If I use `\hyperref[sec:4]{4}` (for example) it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `\stepcounter` by `\refstepcounter`, but without seeing a compilable document, this is guessing only. The labelling mechanism 'relies' on `\refstepcounter`. The explicit `\setcounter{equation}` statements are strange.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That fixed it. Thank you! I had no idea that `\stepcounter` wasn't what I was supposed to be using.

Comment: At this point all you have to do is fixed the incorrect bracing in your `\@@mysubsection` macro and change the three `\stepcounter`s to `\refstepcounter`. That should straighten out things. Perhaps a better question would be how you came up with these definitions in the first place. Maybe something better can be done (there seems to be a lot of code duplication, even if it's just conditioning on whether or not you're in the appendix - `\if@app`).

Comment: @JacobHouse: Perhaps consider reading this: [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)

Comment: @JacobHouse: Better drop that template ... it's weird (as almost all templates). I don't see any advantage over using the regular `\section` etc. from `article`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't like it either; it's for someone else who had strict guidelines of what it was supposed to look like. Like I said, before they just redefined `\thesection` to achieve the desired effect but this impacted equation numbering so here we are... Before it's all said and done I may try to rework it entirely to reduce all the duplicate code as suggested by @Werner.

Comment: @JacobHouse: Changing `\thesection` has multiple side effects. Change `\@seccntformat` rather.

Comment: @JacobHouse: [Your code, with adjustments](https://pastebin.com/1CrvRrPr) works...

Comment: All six `\hspace{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%` instructions could (in fact: should) be replaced by `\noindent`...

Comment: @JacobHouse: Your `\refstepcounter` comes too early for the `appendix` code (`\if@app`), besides that, all that is inside a group, so a change of `\thesection` would not work outside

Comment: @JacobHouse:   Place `\if@app
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
    \fi` before `\refstepcounter{section}` in your `\@@mysection` macro

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, your preamble is set to accomplish six things:

- Change the font sizes used in section, subsection, and subsubsection headers. However, as the new font sizes -- `\Large`, `\large`, and `\normalsize` -- are the defaults for the `article` document class, the associated instructions may simply be omitted.
- Change the numbering style of section-level headers from arabic numerals to uppercase letters for sections located in the appendix. This change is performed automatically if the `\appendix` macro is encountered in the body of the document.
- Automatically indent the first line of a paragraph after sectioning headers. This is accomplished quite easily by loading the `indentfirst` package.
- Change the numbering style for equations, to always prefix the section, subsection, and subsubsection numbers.
- Change the spacing above section, subsection, and subsection headers from rubber lengths to fixed lengths of `24pt`, `18pt`, and `18pt`, respectively.
- Affix a "dot" to section, subsection, and subsection numbers in the associated headers.

These tasks could be achieved succinctly with the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent first line after sectioning headers
\usepackage{etoolbox}    % for "\patchcmd" and "\pretocmd" macros
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % hyperlinking of cross-references

%% Change equation numbering style
\pretocmd{\section}{\numberwithin{equation}{section}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}}{}{}

\makeatletter

%% Change spacing above sectioning headers
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-24pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-18pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-18pt}{}{}

%% Affix "dot" to sectioning numbers
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\ }%       default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable indiv. control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\ }
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\ }
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{\thesubsubsection.\ }

\makeatother
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent first line after sectioning headers
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" and "\pretocmd" macros
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%% Change equation numbering style
\pretocmd{\section}{\numberwithin{equation}{section}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}}{}{}

\makeatletter
%% Change spacing above sectioning headers
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-24pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-18pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-18pt}{}{}

%% Affix "dot" to sectioning numbers
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\ }%       default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable indiv. control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\ }
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\ }
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{\thesubsubsection.\ }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Hello} \label{sec:hello}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\subsection{Good morning} \label{sec:morning}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\subsubsection{Good afternoon} \label{sec:afternoon}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:third} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\appendix % <-- change numbering style of section-level headers

\section{Goodbye} \label{sec:goodbye}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:fourth} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

% Generate cross-references to sectioning headers and to equations:
\ref{sec:hello}, \ref{sec:morning}, \ref{sec:afternoon}, \ref{sec:goodbye}

\eqref{eq:first}, \eqref{eq:second}, \eqref{eq:third}, \eqref{eq:fourth}
\end{document}
```