# \ref{nametable} inside \caption doesn't work

Tags: captions, ref

I have already searched in the forum but also in similar questions I have not found solutions that work for my case.
I'm working with `\documentclass[italian,11pt,a4paper]{article}` and I have a `\ref{}` inside a `\caption` :

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{plots/delta}\hfil
\caption{bla bla bla in tabel \ref{deltatab}.}
\label{lab}
\end {center}
\end{figure}
```

And then the table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\label{deltatab}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
Filter & r & i & z & Y & J & Kw & Kd \\ \hline
 $\Delta mag$ &  0.27 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 0.30 & 0.19 & 0.62 & 0.45\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption.}
\end{table}
```

But within the caption of the figure this produces me a `figure ??`.  This is my package list:

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}, textfont={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\fncyblank}{\fancyhf{}}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={3cm,3cm},vmargin={3cm,3cm}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{3em}{1em}{1em}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Some ideas?

Comment: in addition to the question cited in the answer, this might be useful: [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired reference by placing the `label`of the table *after* its `caption` as shown in the following example. Some more information can be found here: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/134144)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf}, textfont={small},textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{bla bla bla in tabel \ref{deltatab}}
\label{lab}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
Filter & r & i & z & Y & J & Kw & Kd \\ \hline
 $\Delta mag$ &  0.27 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 0.30 & 0.19 & 0.62 & 0.45\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}
\label{deltatab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above MWE, I have also added `textformat=period` to the `caption` options. This way, your captions are automatically followed by a dot and you don't have to include it manually into every caption.

Please also keep in mind the correct loading order of packages, especially regarding `hyperref`. This packages should generally (with some few exceptions) be the last package loaded. Also avoid loading packages more than once.