# `\ref{}` inside `\caption{}` in algorithm2e produces error with beamer

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

The following MWE is self-explanatory:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\label{algoone}
  \caption{Algorithm for solving my problem}
  \While{condition}{
      iterate\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
Here is a faster version of Algorithm \ref{algoone}.

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\label{algotwo}
 % Uncommenting the following line produces an error:
 % \caption{Faster version of Algorithm \ref{algoone}}
  \While{condition}{
      iterate faster\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have two algorithms on different slides of a Beamer presentation. I would like to refer to the other algorithm by its number in the caption to another algorithm. That is, the second caption should read "Faster version of Algorithm 1."

This works fine in an article environment. The textual references also work fine. However, including `\ref{}` in an algorithm caption *in Beamer* produces `! Argument of \@caption has an extra }`.

How can I obtain the desired behavior?

(Placing the label after the caption, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434591/refnametable-inside-caption-doesnt-work), does not work.)

Comment: Just try with either `\caption[]{...}` or `\protect\ref{...}`

Comment: While the problems may seem unrelated, their cause and therefore the solution is exactly the same.