# the cleveref usepackage: \cref

Tags: pdftex, cleveref

When I run the following code (`pdflatex`), 
Command Line:

```
pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=1 "ex_article.tex"
```

Startup Folder: C:\Users\wendy\Desktop\siamart_171218

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\wendy\Desktop\siamart_171218\ex_article.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for loaded.

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Package xr Warning: 
No file ex_supplement.aux
LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
 on input line 35.

No file ex_article.aux.
Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned' on input line 116.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Pre' on page 1 undefined on input line 122.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Alt' on page 1 undefined on input line 122.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Con' on page 1 undefined on input line 122.
Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned' on input line 155.

[3]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 230.

Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned' on input line 1321.

No file ex_article.bbl.
[13] (C:\Users\wendy\Desktop\siamart_171218\ex_article.aux)

gbk2uni, version 0.22, initially implemented by cxterm and ZLB in Jan. 2003
  enhanced by hooklee in Mar. 2003.
  please visit www.ctex.org and www.chinatex.org for more information.
gbk2uni ex_article.out is finished!


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 13)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 20   Bad Boxes: 5
_____________________________________________________________________
```

That's all.

What I get is:

> We present some preliminaries in ??.

Even I can get the  PDF .  I guess if the cleveref.sty is too old to support  the command  \cref ?  But I can't find the new cleveref.sty in the official website. And does it have the relationship with a fact that I delete the ex_article.aux every time. If not, I will get the following message and can't get the pdf.

Don't delete the .aux:

...thod of multipliers\relax}{equation.9}{}}

The original code is:

```
\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart171218}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\input{ex_shared}
\ifpdf
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={matrix information},
  pdfauthor={Wen}
}
\fi
\externaldocument{ex_supplement}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\label{sec:Int}
The paper is organized as follows. We present some preliminaries in \cref{sec:Int}. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make sure that cross references appear as intended LaTeX needs to be run at least twice. On the first run the reference will only be marked as `??`. I don't have `siamart171218` installed at the moment, so I can not test, but assuming `cleveref` is loaded by the class and there are no other errors, the example should compile fine. After a second LaTeX run the `\ref` should show just fine. Did you run LaTeX at least twice?

Comment: Yes, I have. But no helpful....

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings after the second run? I downloaded all the files from https://www.siam.org/Publications/Journals/About-SIAM-Journals/Information-for-Authors, put them in the same folder as your MWE and managed to produce the desired output after running LaTeX twice.

Comment: The `.aux` file is needed for the references to show properly. If you delete it, you will always get `??` in the output instead of the correct reference (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/35864 for a great explanation why that is). So I guess we should investigate why you get the error from your `.aux` file. Unfortunately, the error message you get when you don't delete the `.aux` is cut off. Can you repost it completely and add an MWE that reproduces that error, please?

Comment: I  solved this problem just now~ Don't need to delete the .aux, and input  's'  in your command line window, then your code will continue to run.

Comment: Well, that just forces compilation despite the error. You should really try and find out what causes the error and resolve it. We can help you with that if you want, but we need to see code that reproduces the issue.