# No citation in List of Figures with label

Tags: labels

Here is my MWE:

```
\newcommand{\munepsfig}[4][scale=1.0]{%
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering

        \includegraphics[#1]{Pictures/#2.jpg}
        \caption[#4]{#3}
        \label{#1}
    \end{figure}
}
```

and I am using it like:

```
\munepsfig[scale=0.66]{mm3}{Effect of variation of $\alpha$ on path of node movement \mycite{r22}}{Effect of variation of $\alpha$ on path of node movement}{f3.6}
```

Here f3.6 is my label, but in text it is not appearing. There is ?? in text.

Comment: I guess you want `\label{#4}` instead

Comment: To be a working example, one must be able to run it as is.  What you have is a code fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You  have a number of problems showing and to address the final outcome you will generally get ?? until a successful prior run has updated the aux files see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111281/170109 However you first need a successful 1st run and since your code is based on multiple cut and paste we have no idea what you have pre-set to untangle such a miss-match I would tidy up the command to at least be commented I have taken your word that the label is "f3.6" thus the #5th option

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{#1}
%above added to mwe to provide minimum working

\newcommand{\munepsfig}[5][scale=1.0]{% <--this has been increased to include the 5th option
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
% #1 = [scale] x scale=1.0 e.g. 0.66 x 1.0
% #2 = baseimage name (AVOID spaces / accents / punctuation) also not a good idea to use subfolders NOR specify one format especially jpg
        \includegraphics[#1]{Pictures/#2.jpg}
% #4 = [VERY LONG INVISIBLE DESCRIPTION]
% #3 = short visible snappy caption with included \cite?
        \caption[#4]{#3}
% #5 = set to ?? before compilation only replaced on 2nd run once doc is scanned
        \label{#5}
    \end{figure}
}  
\munepsfig[scale=0.66]{example-image-A}{Effect of variation of $\alpha$ on path of node movement \mycite{r22}}{Visible Effect of variation of $\alpha$ on path of node movement}{f3.6}   

see Figure~\ref{f3.6}

Above will be

1st pass = see Figure ??

2nd pass= see Figure 1
\end{document}
```