# Debugging error message: File ended while scanning use of @ newl@bel

Tags: errors, auxiliary-files

I've done something to my `.tex` file that is resulting in the following error:

> File ended while scanning use of @ newl@bel.  \par 1.137 \begin{document}

This happens even when all the content is commented out.

I've found that duplicating the file and recompiling it temporarily solves the problem. However, once I introduce a syntax error into my LaTeX code, I get the same error, and can't find a way to debug it.  It's driving me nuts.

Comment: This looks like an error that manifests itself in the `.aux` file. The `.aux` file is a temporary file that LaTeX needs to be able to resolve cross references and the like (basically everything that may involve code having to look into the future, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/35864 for a nice explanation of the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism using `.aux` files).

Comment: Errors like this can be a bit of pain to deal with, because they may persist in the temporary file even if the problematic code in the `.tex` file has been fixed or removed completely. Plus, it can be a bit tricky to find the corresponding `.tex` code. Often the error message contains some (con)text that may help you locate the problematic code. If that is not the case, you need to open the `.aux` file, look for the problematic line and hope that it gives some hints as to where it came from in the `.tex` file.

Comment: delete the aux file. Also when you get an error make sure to exit cleanly by typing x not by quitting the window, that can corrupt any files that are being written.

Comment: This might help:  there is another error message that says "Label `fig:exblah` multiply defined. I can't find duplicates of labels that have used this macro. Also, in addition to the .synctec.gz file, there is also a sync.tex(busy) file. The problem goes away when I delete all the associated .gz, .log, .aux, .out, .pdf files and recompile.

Comment: Just saw all these comments.  Thanks for the help!