# Referencing Multiple Tables in Paragraphs

Tags: tables

I am trying to reference multiple tables in a latex text document. I am trying to have two table numbered and within the text can reference the table number so if they are ever rearranged/reordered the text in the table would reference the correct table. I noticed that the two function used for referencing

```
\ref{table:somename}
```

and

```
\label{table:somename}
```

My question: How do I designate in the function which reference`\ref{table:somename}` refers to in the table?

```
 \begin{table}
      \centering%
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Some & text
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{The caption of the table 1}\label{table:somename}
    \end{table}
    In text, I can reference the first Table~\ref{table:somename} like this.


    \begin{table}
      \centering%
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Some & text
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{The caption of the table 2 }\label{table:somename}
    \end{table}
    In text, I can reference the second Table~\ref{table:somename} like this.
```

Comment: Use a unique label for each table.

Comment: I did that problem is I get Table ?? instead of Table 1 or Table 2. Instead I get Table ???, with the two question marks

Comment: Never mind I got it to work but I did exactly what you wrote before and I would get the ?? instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\label` should be unique, otherwise TeX will tell you that you have "multiply defined" labels as a warning when you compile.

In your case, use some descriptive label for each table that is independent of their numbering, perhaps

```
\begin{table}
  % <your first table>
  \caption{First table caption}\label{tab:measurements}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  % <your second table>
  \caption{Second table caption}\label{tab:details}
\end{table}
```

Now you would be able to refer to `Table~\ref{tab:measurements}` and `Table~\ref{tab:details}` and the `\ref`erences will follow any layout changes. You will have to compile twice with every change of the layout in order to let the references settle. See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764) for a discussion on this.