# How to get algorithm numbering instead of section numbering?

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, algorithmic

I am trying to get numbering for algorithm in references, but I am getting reference as section number. How to resolve this? A simple working of my code is as follows

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 .05}]{hyperref}


\usepackage{xcolor}

\hypersetup{%
 colorlinks=true,% hyperlinks will be coloured
 linkcolor=red,% hyperlink text will be green
 linkbordercolor=red,% hyperlink border will be red
 citecolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}

\title{ TMP\\
   \thanks{THX}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{NAME1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{NAME2} \\
}

}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro

\section{Exact Algorithm and Pseudo Code}
\ref{lab:ide_algo}

\begin{algorithm}
       \label{lab:ide_algo}
       \caption{Count-Sort}
       \begin{algorithmic}[1]
           \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
           \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
           \REQUIRE IN
           \ENSURE  OP
           \\ \textit{Initialisation} :
           \STATE STATE
           
       \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change order of `\label` and `\caption`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, changing the order resolved this issue! Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: [Yes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111281/52406), there is.